# Distribute the additions!

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, parsing

**Challenge**: Given an expressions made of additions and multiplications, output an expression that is a sum of products. The output must be equivalent to the input modulo the law of distribution. For example, \$1 + ((2 + 5\times 6) \times(3+4))\$ becomes \$1 + 2 \times 3 + 2 \times 4 + 5\times6\times3 + 5 \times 6 \times 4 \$. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

This task is useful in automatic theorem proving, since the conversion to *[disjunctive normal forms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjunctiveNormalForm.html)* is exactly the same task. (Oops, that gives away a Mathematica builtin!)

**Clarifications**:

- You can assume the numbers are whatever you want, integers, floats, or even just strings of symbols, as long as it's convenient.
- You can use the law of distribution, commutativity and associativity of addition and multiplication. But you cannot use any other property of addition or multiplication. So e.g. \$3 \times (1 + 3) \to 3 + 3 \times 3\$ is not acceptable.
- This means that answers are not unique, the test cases are just a reference.
- Parentheses are optional, you won't need them anyway.
- You can assume any reasonable input form.

**Test cases**:

```
2 -> 2 (Corner case, you can ignore this.)
1+3 -> 1+3
1+(3*4) -> 1+3*4
1+3*4 -> 1+3*4
(1+3)*4 -> 1*4+3*4
(1+2+3)*(4+5+6) -> 1*4+2*4+3*4+1*5+2*5+3*5+1*6+2*6+3*6
(1+2*(3+4))*((5+6)*7)+8 -> 1*5*7+1*6*7+2*3*5*7+2*3*6*7+2*4*5*7+2*4*6*7+8
```

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108747/convert-a-logical-expression-to-conjunctive-normal-form). This challenge is slightly simpler, because you don't have the additional logical identities.

Comment: May we take input as `P(1, M(3, 4))` instead of `1+(3*4))`?

Comment: @user Yes, I think it is already a consensus that this is a reasonable format for syntax-tree-style input.

Comment: Can I define my own addition and multiplication functions and take input as the application of those.  e.g. `f(1*(2+3))="1*2+1*3"`?

Comment: @WheatWizard Ahh, that's exactly what I'm doing when I encountered this problem in real world! I think it's OK.

Comment: shouldn't last test case be `1*5*7+1*6*7+2*3*5* 7 +2*3*6*7+2*4*5*7+2*4*6*7+8` ?

Comment: idea of test case `1*2*3 -> 1*2*3`

Comment: @Jakque Yes, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 139 bytes

```haskell
data M=I Int|M:*M|M:+M deriving(Show,Read)
f(x:*y)|z:+w<-f y=f(x:*z):+f(x:*w)|z:+w<-f x=f(z:*y):+f(w:*y)
f(x:+y)=f x:+f y
f x=x
show.f.read
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsIwEITvfYqleEgaLai3YB4gh1z0CQLpT7CmkhbTlL573BTBy84w3yzT6@nZDENKRs8alJAg3bwpXik8TIFpvP1Y15FHP4bjvdGGFi1ZeBXptnIWbqcWotiTlXK2m/BHC6I1lzMK2ezfLFKBEEOIRW4tRScmXKjb2uNGemnrxNtbNx@6UsIFeAVEwvWnZ@AMMKa0TF8)

### IO Format

Here our IO format uses the functions `:+` for addition and `:*` for multiplication.  We also require that numbers themselves are prefixed with `I` , and that all parentheses be explicit.

So for example

```
2 * (3 * (1 + 2))
```

is

```
I 2 :* (I 3 :* (I 1 :+ I 2))
```

We uses this format because we are parsing into a native haskell data type defined on the first line.  If I could operate on the data type directly the code would be a lot shorter:

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 107 bytes

```haskell
data M=I Int|M:*M|M:+M
f(x:*y)|z:+w<-f y=f(x:*z):+f(x:*w)|z:+w<-f x=f(z:*y):+f(w:*y)
f(x:+y)=f x:+f y
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDsIgEETvfMUm9lBKelBvRG5eSOTkFxBLW2KlpkUptX47QqPxsjuZN5udVo5X1XXhVW7gJE3zkI2Cs5Wmkl1v1FEN@qlNA5vyHSppJQjGgRu7CFqIOIhAdT7RwuNlpsQdyho8W50ZU7IK90dTRHMKJ@SSWK@JxyzCaIJHKTWF6vdYmzG2ucRSbe9AIHST2rD7oI3N6ozDDmgBOYf9d2@BEog2xuED)

Since this gets rid of all the parsing bits and just includes the manipulations.

Comment: You might find some one-character operators for `:+` and `:*`...? Or have you used them up?

Comment: @Trebor Constructors must be named with a starting `:`, and `:` itself is already taken.  I could make an alias but it can't be used in pattern matches and ends up making my code bigger.

Comment: Maybe this is I/O scumming to a degree that trivializes the challenge too much, but combining this input format with a “list-of-lists, sum-of-products” output format (`[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]` meaning `1 + 2×3 + 4×5×6`) makes the implementation very short (`f(x:*y)=(++)<$>f x<*>f y` etc).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 157 bytes

```python
lambda e:"+".join(eval(re.sub("\d","A('\g<0>')",e)))
import re
class A(list):__mul__=lambda s,x:A(i+"*"+j for i in s for j in x);__add__=lambda s,x:A([*s]+x)
```

### How it works :

We define a new object named `A` with the wanted properties for addition and multiplication.

- each digit is stored as a list of string
- an expression like `1+2` is converted into `['1', '2']`
- an expression like `1*2` is converted into `['1*2']`
- the sum is equivalent to the python list addition
- the product is a double iteration over the 2 lists

Then we let python do the multiplication over addition priority

- `re.sub("\d","A('\g<0>')",e)` we convert all the digits in our expression into instances of this object
- `"+".join(eval(...))` we evaluate and formate the result

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7bTsMwDIavyVNEvpmdVBO05aBCkfoc6xR1NIVU6UFJhsrTl6UMLrjy58@y/c9f4WMas7Ur69U2w6ltuC5Awr6fzIj6s7Ho9N6fTwh1CwlUuKvfX25fdwSJJiJmhnlygTvN3mzjPa/QGh@oUGo4W6XK61GfLEWFRoIA2fNuctxwM3K/YR9xoWelmrb9v3MQ/igXWoP2wfPywCCFhMGdzLYiUvEDEjOR03Uk8gh4IfrDNDaYy3v5QL9KYCZzumiMVjySfIIjYzFUiKG2pwW7mZ0ZA3YYiNZv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 118 bytes

```
{`\(([\d*]+)\)
$1
\(([\d*]+)\+([^()]+\))(\*([\d*]+|\([^()]+\)))
$1$3+($2$3
([\d*]+\*)\(([\d*]+)\+([^()]+\))
$1$2+$1($3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYy9DgIxDIP3PkcGO5nalJ93uRwCCQYWBsQG717a4yQYGCLbX@LcL4/r7dTa8xjAFGedjcEkOf1kw3QAZwsSoSt@xZeOgrhBinha96H8/2LcFpMM8dZKyuZ94Fo5vNaELvxoGQ7VNrblkhVulZ1hIN3R9m8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
{`
```

Perform all possible reductions.

```
\(([\d*]+)\)
$1
```

`(a*b*...)` becomes `a*b*...`.

```
\(([\d*]+)\+([^()]+\))(\*([\d*]+|\([^()]+\)))
$1$3+($2$3
```

`(a*b*...+c*d*...+...)*f*g*...` becomes `a*b*...*f*g*...+(c*d*...+...)*f*g*`, where `f*g*...` could instead be `(f*g*...+h*i*...+...)`.

```
([\d*]+\*)\(([\d*]+)\+([^()]+\))
$1$2+$1($3
```

`a*b*...*(c*d*...+e*f*...+...)` becomes `a*b*...*c*d*...+a*b*...(e*f*...+...)`.