# Boustrophedon transform

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer

Related: [Boustrophedonise](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150117/78410), [Output the Euler Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107558/78410) (Maybe a new golfing opportunity?)

### Background

Boustrophedon transform ([OEIS Wiki](https://oeis.org/wiki/Boustrophedon_transform)) is a kind of transformation on integer sequences. Given a sequence \$a_n\$, a triangular grid of numbers \$T_{n,k}\$ is formed through the following procedure, generating each row of numbers in the back-and-forth manner:

$$
\swarrow \color{red}{T_{0,0}} = a_0\\
\color{red}{T_{1,0}} = a_1 \rightarrow \color{red}{T_{1,1}} = T_{1,0}+T_{0,0} \searrow \\
\swarrow \color{red}{T_{2,2}} = T_{1,0}+T_{2,1} \leftarrow \color{red}{T_{2,1}} = T_{1,1}+T_{2,0} \leftarrow \color{red}{T_{2,0}} = a_2 \\
\color{red}{T_{3,0}} = a_3 \rightarrow \color{red}{T_{3,1}} = T_{3,0} + T_{2,2} \rightarrow \color{red}{T_{3,2}} = T_{3,1} + T_{2,1} \rightarrow \color{red}{T_{3,3}} = T_{3,2} + T_{2,0} \\ \cdots
$$

In short, \$T_{n,k}\$ is defined via the following recurrence relation:

$$
\begin{align}
T_{n,0} &= a_n \\
T_{n,k} &= T_{n,k-1} + T_{n-1,n-k} \quad \text{if} \; 0<k\le n
\end{align}
$$

Then the Boustrophedon transform \$b_n\$ of the input sequence \$a_n\$ is defined as \$b_n = T_{n,n}\$.

More information (explicit formula of coefficients and a PARI/gp program) can be found in the OEIS Wiki page linked above.

### Task

Given a finite integer sequence, compute its Boustrophedon transform.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[10] -> [10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] -> [0, 1, 4, 12, 36]
[0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8] -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 7, 15, 78]
[1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1] -> [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 10, 61]
```

Brownie points for beating or matching my 10 bytes in ngn/k or 7 bytes in Jelly.

Comment: A new Bubbler avatar!

Comment: The Euler number used in the Boustrophedon transform is not OEIS A122045 (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107558/9288), but OEIS A000111 (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248143/9288)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 7 bytes

```
;UÄµ\Ṫ€
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCI7VcOEwrVcXOG5quKCrCIsIiIsIiIsWyJbMCwgMSwgLTEsIDIsIC0zLCA1LCAtOF0iXV0=)

Given the previous row, we can reverse it, append it to the next element in the source list, and cumulatively sum. (Reverse + append-to is the same as append + reverse)

Therefore:

```
;UÄµ\Ṫ€    Main Link
    \      Cumulatively reduce the source list; each time, with the
           last row as the left and the next element as the right:
;          Append the element to the last row
 U         Reverse the whole thing
  Ä        Cumulative sum
     Ṫ€    Get the last element of each
```

Comment: I had R underdot in place of U and last-3-dyad instead of chain separator. Essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Bubbler Ah, interesting. I usually just throw a `µ` in before the quick so I can do whatever I want in the link before without needing to worry about how many links to combine, and then can't be bothered to use the combining quick :P and also U is easier to type so I use it whenever there is no difference lol

Comment: ` and also U is easier to type`. Wait, Jelly coders actually type the code themselves? I thought they are using some other programs to convert them into the right symbols.

Comment: @justhalf usually people just copy-paste it off the wiki; on the JHT site (which I created) you can use alt-enter to combine characters, so for example, I can type R underdot by doing `R.` and then pressing alt-enter. I still end up copy-pasting a lot because I haven't memorized everything but for really common built-ins I can just type them. Some people also have keyboard layouts (US INTL specifically) that can type all of Jelly's characters.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>47</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
f:{i{$[y;o[x;y-1]+o[x-1;x-y];a x]}'i:!#a:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qOrNaJbrSOj@6wrpS1zBWG8jQNbSu0K2MtU5UqIitVc@0UlROtKqo/Z8WbaBgqGCkYKxgEvsfAA)

A function taking an array of numbers. -5 thanks to ngn. -1 thanks to Razetime.

```
{                          // A function returning...
  {                        // A function, returning
    $[                     // A switch statemnet
      y;                   // If y (second arg) is nonzero
      o[x;y-1]+o[x-1;x-y]; // Do a recursive call
      a x                  // Else index x into a
    ]       
  }'i:                     // Call with the first argument as both arguments
  '!#a:x}                    // Map this over a range of the same length as the input, which we also assign to a for later use
```

Comment: Remove the function prelude for [41](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qOrNaJbrSOj@6wrpS1zBWG8jQNbSu0K2MtU5UqIitVc@0UlROtKqo/Z8WbaBgqGCkYKxgEssF5OgoGOoo6AKxEZAy1lEwBVIWsf8B "K (oK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(g=(k,n,x)=>x?g(n,n):k?g(k-1,n)+g(n-k,n-1):a[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrNCsIwEATgu0@RYxZ3S@MPSCH1QUoPS22Dpm6KFenbxwU9ST3NMPPd@MVz97hOT5J06fPgM/uaiztPNngbUXABXy/nYAUFqqglktO61YX0JwcVN9JC7pLMaeyLMQU72MaVLcDmZyzRODQ7NHs0h78/fQwpOmqcVuBXrYTi/AY)

Comment: Oh, using the same function for map and recurse. That's very clever.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map((_,i)=>(T=(n,k)=>k?T(n,k-1)+T(n-1,n-k):a[n])(i,i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNDkAwEEDh68zEVBQrSbmEnYhM/KXKVBDXr9p9yXsbv3yPlz0fJX6aw2ICm5rTg0@AgSyaGloDQi7KNe0vpTGJUJpEOay4kx7BxhfD6OX2@5zufoUFuow05VRQ2cf2AQ)

Copying the formula described in the question.

```javascript
a => a.map(                           // Map a
  (_, i) =>                           // By index, we don't care about the content of a, just that it's the right length
  ( T = (n, k) =>                     // Declare a function T, taking n and k
      k ?                             // If k is nonzero...
        T(n, k - 1) + T(n - 1, n - k) // Do a recursive call
      : a[n]                          // Else index n into a
  )(i, i))                            // Call this function with i,i as arguments.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
’1ŀ_+1ŀ’}¥ð‘ị³ðṛ?
J’Ç€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0zDow3x2kACyKw9tPTwhkcNMx7u7j60@fCGhztn23N5AcUPtz9qWvP///9oAx0FQx0FIx0FYx0Fk1gA)

Horrible recursive definition, I'm sure there's a better approach. Full program. [Here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0zDow3x2kACyKw9tPTwhkcNMx7u7j607vCGhztn23N5AcUPtz9qWvP/0M5DKw@3H530cOcMzcj//6MNDWJ1FKINdBQMdRSMdBSMdRRMEAK6EEFdoKgpkLIAyUCFsVCxAA)'s a modified version to run as a test suite.

### How it works

We just implement

$$T(n,k) = \begin{cases}
a_n & \text{if } k = 0 \\
T(n-1,n-k) + T(n, k-1) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

then calculate \$T(i,i)\$ for each index \$i\$ of \$a\$

The first line defines \$T(n,k)\$, and the second calculates \$T(i,i)\$ for each index \$i\$.

```
’1ŀ_+1ŀ’}¥ð‘ị³ðṛ? - Helper link. T(n,k).
               ṛ? - If k:
          ð       -   Then:
’                 -     n-1
   _              -     n-k
 1ŀ               -     T(n-1, n-k)
         ¥        -     Last two links as a dyad g(n,k):
       ’}         -       k-1
     1ŀ           -       T(n, k-1)
    +             -     T(n-1, n-k) + T(n, k-1)
              ð   -   Else:
           ‘      -     n+1 (due to Jelly's 1 indexing)
            ị³    -     Index into a

J’Ç€ - Main link. Takes a on the left
J    - Indices of a
 ’   - Decrement to 0 index
   € - Over each index i:
  Ç  -   Yield T(i,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
ＦＡ«⊞υιＵＭυΣ…⮌υ⊕λＩ✂υ±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CsIwFEbn9inueAMRrLo5ZuqgFDuWDiG9mkB@SpoURHz22OI3Hs75lJZRBWlLeYYI2Po5J2QMPnXV5UVj5mDYta5uchbBOemnHfXZoXgrS0KHGR@0UlwIM@PQehXJkU80oWXbtraLxicUcknYW6Nof7jTSybC5q98SxmGI4eGw4nDmcNlHMthtT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＡ«
```

Loop over the input list.

```
⊞υι
```

Push the current input value to the Boustrophedon list.

```
ＵＭυΣ…⮌υ⊕λ
```

Take the sums of all the nontrivial suffixes of the list to produce the new list.

```
Ｉ✂υ±¹
```

Output the last member of the new list on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.size.times.map &g=->n,k=n{k<1?l[n]:g[n,k-1]+g[n-1,n-k]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkevOLMqVa8kMze1WC83sUBBLd1W1y5PJ9s2rzrbxtA@Jzov1io9GiigaxirDWToGurk6WbH1tb@L1BIi4420DHUMdIx1jGJjf0PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Å»ª.sO}€θ
```

Port of [*@hyper-neutrino♦*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233517/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOuh3YdW6RX71z5qWnNux///0QY6hjq6hjpGOrrGOqY6uhaxAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w62Hdh9apVfsX/uoac25Hf91/kdHGxrE6kQb6BjqGOkY65hA2bogrq6xjqmOrgVQCCyASsTGAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Å»      # Cumulative left-reduce the (implicit) input-list by:
  ª     #  Appending the current item to the list
   .s   #  Get the suffices of this list
     O  #  Sum each inner list together
 }€θ    # After the reduce, only leave the last element of each inner list
        # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```