# Increasing permutation trees

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, permutations, graph-theory, binary-tree

For this challenge a "binary tree" is a rooted tree where each node has 0 children (leaf) or 2.  The children of a node are unordered, meaning that while you might *draw* the tree with left and right children there isn't a distinction between them and mirroring the tree or a sub-tree  does not produce a new tree.

In this challenge you will be given an integer \$n\$ and you will be asked to determine the number of binary trees with each node labeled from \$1\$ to \$2n+1\$ such that no child node is less than its parent.

For example the following tree with 7 nodes is valid:

```
     1
 2    7
3  4
  5 6
```

but the following tree is not:

```
     1
 2    7
6  4
  5 3
```

Since `3` is a child of `4`.

## Task

Given \$n\$ calculate the number of binary trees labeled from \$1\$ to \$2n+1\$ such that no child node is less than its parent.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

## Test cases

I've calculated the first 11 solutions on my own:

```
1, 1, 4, 34, 496, 11056, 349504, 14873104, 819786496, 56814228736, 4835447317504
```

and the OEIS has more terms at: [A002105](https://oeis.org/A002105)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 72 bytes

```
lambda n:(mat(tril(cumsum(r_[1:n+3]),1),"O")**n)[0,0]
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3PXISc5NSEhXyrDRyE0s0SooyczSSS3OLS3M1iuKjDa3ytI1jNXUMNXWU_JU0tbTyNKMNdAxiudKK8nMV8kpzCyoVMnML8otKtCDm7UvLL1LIU8jMUyhKzEtP1TAy0LQqKMrMK9FI08jT1IQoWrAAQgMA)

Same as below but as a function (no outer loop):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 85 bytes

```
from numpy import*
a=1,
for s,in r_:print((mat(tril(a,1),"O")**s).A1[0]);a+=a[s]+s+2,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NYyxCsIwFEX3fMWjU5LGkjhJpYKjk5NTKRKwwYBJSl4K9ltcuug_9W-Uti733OHc-_p0Q7oHP04n67oQE-CAJHTR-lTNSW6tgblRZCUBawAPSnKupCx_ctE-baKMQPhL7z6ZzW66mBgc-N51AyzfnOhKCWJCBBTWQ7yWy4Y6nWiK9kG1UExk54xxjqw4qlo2bK_zStfY5JhvxXI-rlj5BQ)

Uses the production matrix approach from the OEIS page. Preamble doctors `print` to cut short the infinite loop (otherwise ato swallows the output).
Uses [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237487/101374) trick to set up the infinite loop.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>85</s> 80 bytes

```python
def f(n,s=1,*a):
 for _ in"__"*~-n:a=s,*[s:=s+x for x in a[::-1]]
 print(s>>~-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCoAgEIDhvac4mswMkpY4sBeJEKGslku8hlp6dbPm/@MP97kd1PUhpjQvHrwgxUYr6SoswB8RLOxUWlvKpyF0hpUcGQ3X11@vXMGNiI2epgJC3OkUPAwZV@kD9IHoaF2EVqDbfytyfAE) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Based on  the relation `A002105(n) = A000111(2n-1)/2ⁿ⁻¹`, calculates A000111 using @dingledooper's approach to [Count alternating permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248143/). Edit: Saved 5 bytes with help from @pexger.

Comment: `for _ in range(n+n-2)` -> `for _ in"_"*~-n*2` for 81 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw9CoQwEEDh3lMMVklMYGdtZCBeREQCa1abMWQs3GavHn/q9/HSb182bruUS/nMEaJiKx6tCZoqiFuGCVaup9r8HZs3BS/WDEJemuPJx5UhDEQOx7GClFfelfQ9O9TlBnyDHPg7K7SAr@erWJcT "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @pxeger Even I know a golfier way of saying `"_"*2`...

Comment: Heh, good point.

Answer (score 4):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), <sup><s>44</s> <s>42</s></sup> 36 bytes

```python
lambda n:2*(-2)**n*polylog(1-2*n,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFT8tugzAQvCPxD3uzcY0UGwMmEv2RpgdKlgSVGASO1Bbx713TtNdaa2lnHzOzXX2Ko6G5vZ0bcEcteKoTIZyYxuFzGC9cpVo4maokjuC_F0f4MWHr8Qw1cCWBwkjI6JuqIKgOeRFwlR-opowtMxUyq6rSFvtMXlhltKYOAWOz3BgaKmmBHHhc_ELcc-MuGAQGdPxXM4EnCDbbK7bvOAcL7HTXpWmZhD1TGaN-N87gJULv4Kuf-M4p4Y_l-HNokOm4f5w9zb3zvGOr3yB9hnXZYH3ovGBdL68bS74BSu5RXA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

*Saved <s>2</s> 8 bytes thanks to [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)!!!*

Uses a port of the Mathematica code by Vladimir Reshetnikov on the [OEIS A002105](https://oeis.org/A002105) page.

Comment: -2 byte: `lambda n:(-2)**n*(1-4**n)*bernoulli(2*n)/n`

Comment: Or shorter using the Mathematica code by Vladimir Reshetnikov on OEIS: `lambda n:2*(-2)**n*polylog(1-2*n,-1)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 23 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Based on Peter Luschny's Sage function on OEIS.

```
1⊑(0∾2×+`∘⌽⍟2)⍟⊑∘⥊÷2××˜
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkDHiipEoMOKIvjLDlytg4oiY4oy94o2fMinijZ/iipHiiJjipYrDtzLDl8OXy5wKCgpGwqgxK+KGlTEw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊞υ¹Ｆ⊖⊗θ≔⊞Ｏ⮌ＥυΣ…υ⊕λ⁰υＩ÷§υ⁰Ｘ²⊖θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwDIbvPkWPKUxQwdNOsl12UIc@QddFV@jaLW2nPn1td9FAyE/I/@WXgyBphY6xMVPwlzB2SDDzctMGN0Ao2D7phyUGNUrCEY3HHmobOp3mzDlnJ@fU00A2XCck4S3BDRckh3AWU4bcwwjVR2qsBrsuGvODaZ6rYLvUIX8mZTxUwnlojK/VonqEk29Mj@/szXetfaWch4L9p5pXUBnjMW4X/QU) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Combining two formulas on A110501 gives A002105 in terms of A000111, which we did a couple of days ago: `A002105(n) = A000111(2n-1)/2ⁿ⁻¹`.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
⊞υ¹Ｆ⊖⊗θ≔⊞Ｏ⮌ＥυΣ…υ⊕λ⁰υ
```

Calculate `A000111(2n-1)`. See my answer to [Count alternating permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248143/).

```
Ｉ÷§υ⁰Ｘ²⊖θ
```

Divide by `2ⁿ⁻¹`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes

```
EulerE[2#-1,0](-2)^#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737U0J7XINdpIWddQxyBWQ9dIM05Z7X9AUWZeSbSygq6dQlq0cmysmoK@g0JQYl56qoKDgqHhfwA)

This is basically the Mathematica code by Vladimir Reshetnikov on OEIS, but golfed down.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 99 bytes

```
D=[1]
i=0
while 1:exec"D[::-1]=D\nfor k in range(i):D[k+1]+=D[k]\n"*2;D+=0,;print(D[i]<<i)/-~i;i+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN5NdbKMNY7kybQ24yjMyc1IVDK1SK1KTlVyirax0DWNtXWLy0vKLFLIVMvMUihLz0lM1MjWtXKKztQ1jtW2BdGxMnpKWkbWLtq2BjnVBUWZeiYZLdGasjU2mpr5uXaZ1pratIcQqqI0wmwE)

-14 bytes thanks to @ovs

Based on [Peter Luschny](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Peter_Luschny)'s program on the OEIS page.

Full program which prints the sequence infinitely.

`exec"..."*2` performs two cumulative sums on `D`, first backwards, then forwards.

A backwards cumulative sum is equivalent to:

```
D.reverse()
D.normal_cumulative_sum()
D.unreverse()
```

Since "unreverse" is the same as reverse, the overall sequence of operations becomes:

```
D.reverse()
D.normal_cumulative_sum()
D.reverse()
D.normal_cumulative_sum()
```

and this can be extracted into a snippet of code which we just call twice.

`D[::-1]=D` is a horrible way of reversing `D` in-place, which is two bytes shorter than `D.reverse()`. Unlike the more obvious `D=D[::-1]`, it doesn't reassign `D` (it mutates it in-place), which means it can be done in a function without having to use the `global` keyword.

Comment: `exec` saves a couple bytes over defining a function, and you can actually start with  `D=[1]` with some rearrangements. And `range(i)` saves a bit over `R`

Comment: @ovs I'm not sure if this is exactly what you meant?

Comment: This is close, I had [99 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN5NdbKMNY7kybQ24yjMyc1IVDK1SK1KT1V2irax0DWNtXWLy0vKLFLIVMvMUihLz0lM1MjWtXKKztQ1jtW2BdGxMnrqWkbWLtq2BjnVBUWZeiYZLdGasjU2mpr5uXaZ1pratIcQqqI0wmwE)

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 27 bytes

```
n->(-2)^n*eulerpol(2*n-1)%x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWu_N07TR0jTTj8rRSS3NSiwryczSMtPJ0DTVVKyAqbqqk5Rdp5CnYKhjqKBga6CgUFGXmlQAFlBR07YBEmkaepqYmRO2CBRAaAA)

Based on the Mathematica code by Vladimir Reshetnikov on OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 125 bytes

```
C=lambda n,k:n==k or C(n-1,k)*n//(n-k)
def f(n):
    s=i=0
    while(i<n)*n:j=n-i-1;s+=f(i)*f(j)*C(2*n,2*i+1);i+=1
    return s//2or 1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY47DoMwEERrfIotbQMCU0WQrTgJETgskAUZUEiRk6ShSe6U24T8uhlpRu_dHsNlqnte1_s82XD3vObYFadDWQAHbcqILfQOcsmhCVqlOYq22CpRVhasZJUKb0TCWHjnmrpK0p63VdoghxSabPTRSlLaykbpXCaag0STb1RGPhrhuWqaHcMYRcmGMT8JbbfCQAyu4GMlTfzmLIAfpPAGRzxJDmBR38df_wU)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

-2 [jezza_99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110555/jezza-99)

```python
lambda n:2*(-2)**n*polylog(1-2*n,-1)
from mpmath import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXISc5NSEhXyrIy0NHSNNLW08rQK8nMqc_LTNQx1jbTydHQNNbnSivJzFXILchNLMhQycwvyi0q0IPpXFxRl5pVopGmYaWpCRBYsgNAA)

Ported from code by Vladimir Reshetnikov from the OEIS page ([A002105](https://oeis.org/A002105))

Comment: The `f=` can be excluded for [-2 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXISc5NSEhXyrIy0NHSNNLW08rQK8nMqc_LTNQx1jbTydHQNNbnSivJzFXILchNLMhQycwvyi0q0IPpXFxRl5pVopGmYaWpCRBYsgNAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,s=0,l=1)=>n?s*f(n-=.5,s-1,l+1)+l*f(n,s+1,l):!s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCsIwEETv/YoVesiapDQHQVpXf6WhNqKEjXTFS8i3xwgDwxse8/JfL@v@fH8sp/tWA7UoNkKjieSQrnyTY1BsaTgZsc5E7VDH/2REN8TpIDWkXTEQjDMwXODcSmuE3AGsiSXFbYjpoRav@swFm9nn9oBlwbkr9Qc)

This program output `true` for `n=0`. 1 more byte is required to convert it into `1`.

```javascript
f=(
  n,    // nodes: `2*n` is number of nodes remaining
  s=0,  // slots: how many nodes with 1 child currently
  l=1   // leaves: how many leaf nodes currently
)=>
  n? // is all nodes placed on the tree?
    s*f(n-=.5,s-1,l+1)+ // chose a non-leaf node, place it as an child
    l*f(n,s+1,l):       // chose a leaf node, place it as an child
  !s // make sure all non-leaf nodes have 2 children
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>66</s>  65 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 0-indexed.

Uses [@Neil's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248214/58563).

```javascript
n=>(g=a=>i<2*n?g([s,...a.map(_=>s+=a[--j],j=i++)]):s>>n)([i=s=1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDoIwEADQna@4geFOoFEnI1z9EELkgkBK4EqocSF8e2V6y5vkJ6Hb3Pot1H/6OHBUtjiysHXV/aKvEeuQG2PELLLim23IWOqimJp8Ypdl1NAzWKuEtePAt4bi4DdUYLiWoFDB4@R8sCcAndfg597MfsRWMN31oHOm@4BKR0tlcsQ/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.extras`, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
[| n | n 2^ 4 n ^ 1 - * n 2 * bernoulli abs * n / ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlBCsIwFET3PcWsRSsRV3oAceNGXJUWfkKqgfQnJr@g4N1jW13Mm8dMT0ZCKrfr@XI6YCB5LKjtSxLlnyfiu/17P7IRFzgj2@do2UyHD4Z8RkxW5B2TY8GxqpRCo9a6Lc0HjDm7DvupOihssJqHidomDqP3DqTzsm7RloEi6vIF)

Uses the following formula from the title of OEIS [A002105](https://oeis.org/A002105):

$$\large\frac{2^n\times(2^{2n}-1)\times|\text{bernoulli}(2n)|}{n}$$

-3 bytes from peeking at @Noodle9's [SageMath answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248217/97916) which combines \$2^{2n}\$ into \$4^n\$.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
\(n){for(i in 2:(2*n))T=rev(diffinv(T));T[1]/2^n*2}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3jWM08jSr0_KLNDIVMvMUjKw0jLTyNDVDbItSyzRSMtPSMvPKNEI0Na1Dog1j9Y3i8rSMaiFad8I1GVoZGmgqFGfkl2ukaWRqakLkFyyA0AA)

Uses the `A002105(n) = A000111(2n-1)/2ⁿ⁻¹` trick found by [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248213/55372), and [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248152/55372) to [Count alternating permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248143/count-alternating-permutations) (calculating A000111).