# Is it within the Cantor set?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, fractal, rational-numbers

## The Challenge

For this challenge, you are supposed to determine if a given number is in the Cantor set. So first, let's define the Cantor set.

First, start with the numbers between 0 and 1. Any numbers outside this range are not in the Cantor set. Now, let's divide the numbers into three equal parts: [0,1/3], [1/3,2/3], [2/3, 1]. Any numbers not inside the ranges of the first and last parts are not in the Cantor set. Now, you repeat this process for the segments [0,1/3] and [2/3, 1]. Then you repeat on what is leftover. You keep on doing this forever. In the end, all numbers that are remaining are in the Cantor set. Here is a diagram of the first six iterations:

[image: Cantor diagram]

---

## Input

Two integer `x` and `y`.
`0 < y < 2^15`
`0 <= x <= y`
The greatest common denominator of `x` and `y` is 1, unless `x == 0`.

---

## Output

Truthy if `x/y` is in the Cantor set.
Falsy if `x/y` is not in the Cantor set.

---

## Examples

Now, let's see some examples of numbers that are in the Cantor set.

```
1/3 -> true
```

It is on a boundary, and boundaries are never removed.

```
1/4 -> true
```

`1/4` is never in the middle third of a segment, though it is never on the boundary either. If you follow it's path, you will actually find that it alternates between being in the first and last thirds of a section.

```
1/13 -> true
```

`1/13` alternates between the first, first, and last sections.

```
1/5 -> false
```

`1/5` falls into the first empty block of the third row in the above diagram, between 1/9 and 2/9.

Other test cases:

```
0/4 -> true
3/10 -> true
3/4 -> true
10/13 -> true
1/1 -> true
12/19 -> false
5/17 -> false
3/5 -> false
1/7 -> false
1/2 -> false
```

You can try other numbers with this snippet:

```js
function isCantor(t,r){var n=new Set;if(0>r)return isCantor(-t,-r);if(0==r)return!1;if(0>t||t>r)return!1;for(;;){if(t%r===0)return!0;if(1===Math.floor(t/r))return!1;if(n.has(t))return!0;n.add(t),t=t%r*3}}$("#test").click(function(){var t=parseInt($("#x").val()),r=parseInt($("#y").val());if(isNaN(t)||isNaN(r)||0==r)return void $("#result").text("Invalid input");var n=isCantor(t,r),i=(n?"I":"Not i")+"n the Cantor set.";$("#result").text(i)});
```

```css
input{width:30px}button{margin-left:7px}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><input id=x>/<input id=y><button id=test>Test</button><p id=result>
```

---

## Objective

The person with the least bytes wins.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the input is not (0,0)? Is the fraction given in simplest form?

Comment: @xnor look at the range given for y. I'm going to say that the fraction is in simplest form unless `x == 0`

Comment: Some test cases where x!=1 would be good. Also, your snippet says 1/3 is not in the cantor set.

Comment: @xnor Added and fixed ;)

Comment: Can we take the input directly as a fraction `x/y`?

Comment: If i enter 1/13 in your test snipet i get a recursion error

Comment: @RomanGräf Odd, I don't have that problem.

Comment: @RomanGräf Tell me if you have that problem again. The snippet no longer uses recursion.

Comment: *Cantor can it be found?*

Comment: @mbomb007 Lol, that's pretty good.

Comment: Related: [OEIS A054591](http://oeis.org/A054591)

Comment: Not sure if "within" in the title is the best word considering that the Cantor set is [meagre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) and [its interior is empty](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133454/describe-the-interior-of-cantor-set). Maybe use "in" instead (as you do in the text)?

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica, 54 bytes

```
If[Last@#===1,Most@#,#]&@RealDigits[#,3][[1]]~FreeQ~1&
```

Unnamed function taking a fraction `x/y` as input, where `y > 0` and `0 ≤ x ≤ y`, and returning `True` or `False`.

A real number between 0 and 1 is in the Cantor set precisely when none of the digits in its base-3 expansion equals 1; the exception is that a fraction whose denominator is a power of 3 (whose base-3 expansion therefore terminates) is allowed to end in a 1.

`RealDigits[#,3][[1]]` gives all of the digits in the base-3 expansion of the fractional input `#`, in a form like `{1, 0, 2, {0, 1, 0, 2}}`: the last list is the periodic part of the expansion, while the integers beforehand are the digits before the periodicity starts. If the base-3 expansion is periodic right away, the output is like `{{0, 1, 0, 2}}`; if the base-3 expansion terminates, the form is like `{1, 0, 2}`.

So we want to check, using `~FreeQ~1`, whether the list is free of `1`s or not. However, because of the terminating expansion thing, we want to delete the last element of the list if it equals `1`; that's what `If[Last@#===1,Most@#,#]` accomplishes. (The `===` is needed to compare a potential list with `1`: `==` alone remains unevaluated in that situation.)

Comment: Im surprised that Mathematica does not have `IsCantorNumber` but has a function to determine is something [is a goat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71631/upgoat-or-downgoat).

Comment: Well, I dunno, which come up more in real life: goats or fractals? ;)

Comment: `FreeQ[RealDigits[#,3][[1]]/.{{x___,1}}:>{x},1]&`

Comment: Such a rule would also strip off trailing `1`s in the periodic part, which leads to incorrect answers. For example, the base-3 expansion of 7/8 is .21212121...., or `{{2,1}}`; but the suggested rule would change that to `{{2}}`, which is free of `1`s but shouldn't be.

Comment: Touché. How about `#==0||FreeQ[RealDigits[#,3]/.{{x___,1},_}:>{x},1]&`? If it's terminating and nonzero `RealDigits[#,3]` will be of the form `{{__Integer},-1}` and if it's repeating it will be of the form `{{___Integer,{__Integer}},-1}`, right? I'm on mobile so it's hard to test right now. If this works, using infix notation for `RealDigits` might work as well.

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```c
f(x,y,i){for(i=y;i--&&x<y;)x=(y-x<x?y-x:x)*3;return x<=y;}
```

Exploits the symmetry of the Cantor set. Breaks after `y` iterations to avoid an infinite loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#PVDtbsMgDPwdnsJqlQpasqZfmlbI9iBbf0wj0SytpEpTyTTKs2cmzSYdxj7fgWGoJOmgUXVV3UgsgsEsWyzIBqOokCEjS28cj6SWO9OU7a3xQJZ1/TBH//VzcyXYa@uwfvp@FQJ9C/R@ggI6yDXATkdsON0wtswcHgwDejPqw6TfP4RxmxQvvJ51tHDcRv1oOH@ilwo6kcQKmU14epDIx@QGECxc8V7WFRCs/9IlcWe1Gm3JpWFnJWepW6fuCKn78DPNg@NJ8zgx8r/8V0oZkfR8y/T@3IheDL8)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
,ạµ%⁹×3µÐĿ:⁹Ḅ3ḟ
```

Prints **3** for truthy, nothing for falsy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6/zcNfCQ1tVHzXuPDzd@NDWwxOO7LcCch7uaDF@uGP@f2ulw8v1HzWtcf//P9pQxzhWRwFImUAoQyjXFEQZQESNdQwNIDREkQFclSGYMtIxtAQxTHUMzSHqTCHS5hDKKBYA)

#### Background

A well-known property of the Cantor set is that it contains precisely those numbers between **0** and **1** that can be written without **1**'s in their ternary expansion.

Note that some numbers – precisely the right edges of the closed intervals involved in the set's construction – can be written either with a single (trailing) **1** or with an infinite amount of trailing **2**'s. For example, **1 = 1<sub>3</sub> = 0.22222…<sub>3</sub>** and **1/3 = 0.1<sub>3</sub> = 0.022222…<sub>3</sub>**, just as **0.5<sub>10</sub> = 0.499999…<sub>10</sub>**.

To avoid special-casing the right edges, we can check for **1**'s is the shortest decimal expansion in both **x/y** and **1 - x/y = (y - x)/y**, where **x/y** is a right edge iff **(y - x)/y** is a left edge. If at least one of them contains no **1**'s, **x/y** belongs to the Cantor set.

#### How it works

```
,ạµ%⁹×3µÐĿ:⁹Ḅ3ḟ  Main link. Left argument: x. Right argument: y

 ạ               Absolute difference; yield y - x.
,                Pair; yield [x, y - x].
       µ         Begin a new, monadic chain with argument [a, b] := [x, y - x].
  µ     ÐĿ       Repeatedly execute the links in between until the results are no
                 longer unique, updating a and b after each execution. Return the
                 array of all unique results.
   %⁹              Compute [a % y, b % y].
     ×3            Compute [3(a % y), 3(b % y)].
                 This yields all unique dividends of the long division of x by y in
                 base 3.
          :⁹     Divide all dividends by y to get the corresponding ternary digits.
            Ḅ    Unbinary; turn [1, 1] into 3, other pairs into other numbers.
             3ḟ  Remove all occurrences of the resulting numbers from [3], leaving
                 an empty array if and only if one pair [a, b] is equal to [1, 1].
```

Comment: `3` is the true `true` +1.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 65 <s>67</s>

**Edit** 2 bytes saved thx @Luke

```js
n=>d=>(z=>{for(q=0;~-q*n*!z[n];n=n%d*3)z[n]=1,q=n/d|0})([])|q!=1|!n
```

*Less golfed*

```js
n=>d=>{
  z = []; // to check for repeating partial result -> periodic number
  for(q = 0; q != 1 && n != 0 && !z[n]; )
    z[n] = 1,
    q = n / d | 0,
    n = n % d * 3
  return q!=1 | n==0
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=
n=>d=>(z=>{for(q=0;~-q*n*!z[n=n%d*3];q=n/d|0)z[n]=1})([])|q!=1|!n
  

console.log(
'Truthy: 1/3 1/4 1/13 0/4 3/10 3/4 10/13 1/1\nFalsey: 1/5 12/19 5/17 3/5 1/7 1/2'.replace(/(\d+).(\d+)/g,(a,x,y)=>a+':'+f(x)(y))
)
```

Comment: I think you can replace `n=n%d*3` with `q=n/d|0` and then replace `z[n]` with `z[n=n%d*3]`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```
y=>f=(x,z,n=~y,q=x/y|0)=>n?!z|!q&&f(x%y*3,z|q==1,n+1):1
```

Use by currying in the denominator first and the numerator second. The standard form is a byte longer:

```
f=(x,y,z,n=~y,q=x/y|0)=>n?!z|!q&&f(x%y*3,y,z|q==1,n+1):1
```

#### Explanation

If a fraction is not in the Cantor set, it must fall into one of the middle sections at some point; therefore, its representation in base 3 must contain a 1 followed at some point by a non-zero digit. That's how this works:

- `z` keeps track of whether we've found a 1.
- `q` is the current digit in base 3.
- `!z|!q` is true if `z` is false (we have not found a 1) or `q` is false (the current digit is 0).

If `n` runs down to zero before we find a non-zero digit somewhere after a 1, the fraction is in the Cantor set and we return `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 62 bytes

```bash
dc -e3o9d$2^$1*$2/p|tr -cd 012|grep -P "1(?!(0{$2,}|2{$2,})$)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SrKCbapxvmaJiFKdiqKVipF9QU1KkoJucomBgaFSTXpRaoKAboKBkqGGvqGFQrWKkU1tjBKY0VTSV/v//b/jf0BgA)

Pass it two integer arguments with arg1 <= arg2 and 0 < arg2.

The output is returned in the exit code (0 for falsy, 1 for truthy), as allowed by [PPCG I/O methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5330#5330).

I suspect the regex can be golfed further, maybe even eliminating the tr command in favor of using grep -z, but this is the shortest I've been able to come up with.  (Unfortunately, grep -z is incompatible with grep -P, and the -P option to get perl-style regexes is required for the ?! syntax.)

Testbed program and output:

```bash
for x in '1 3' '1 4' '1 13' '1 5' '0 4' '3 10' '3 4' '10 13' '1 1' '12 19' '5 17' '3 5' '1 7' '1 2'
  do
    printf %-6s "$x "
    ./cantor $x >/dev/null && echo F || echo T
  done

1 3   T
1 4   T
1 13  T
1 5   F
0 4   T
3 10  T
3 4   T
10 13 T
1 1   T
12 19 F
5 17  F
3 5   F
1 7   F
1 2   F
```

---

**Explanation**

dc part (the arguments are x and y):

```bash
3o     Set output base to 3.
9      Push 9 on the stack.
d      Duplicate the top of the stack. (The extra 9 on the stack isn't actually used, but I need some delimiter in the code here so that the 9 doesn't run into the number coming up next.  If I used a space as a no-op, then I'd need to quote it for the shell, adding an extra character.)
$2^    Raise 9 to the y power. This number in base 3 is 1 followed by 2y 0's.
$1*$2/ Multiply the base-3 number 10....0 (with 2y 0's in it) by x and then divide by y (truncating). This computes 2y digits (after an implied ternary point) of x/y.  That's enough digits so that the repeating part of the rational number is there at least twice.
p      Print the result, piping it to tr.
```

tr and grep part:

A minor issue is that, although dc handles arbitrarily large integers, when dc prints a large number, it will break it up into 69-character lines, with each line except the last ending with a backslash, and with a newline after each line.

The tr command deletes any backslashes and newlines.  This leaves just a single line.

The grep command then uses a perl-style regex (-P option, which is a GNU extension). The regex matches if the line contains a 1 not followed by at least y 0's or at least y 2's which then end the string.

This is exactly what's needed to identify x/y as not being in the Cantor set, because the repeating part of the base-3 representation of the rational number x/y can be viewed as starting at digit #y+1 after the ternary point, and is at most y digits long.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (19 bytes)

```
{_@3@#*\/3b0-W<1&!}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22%2Ftf%22%22%2010%22er%22-%3Erueals%22-~%5D3%2F%7B~%40%40%0A%0A%7B_%403%40%23*%5C%2F3b0-W%3C1%26!%7D%0A%0A~%3D%7D%25&input=0%2F4%20-%3E%20true%0A3%2F10%20-%3E%20true%0A3%2F4%20-%3E%20true%0A10%2F13%20-%3E%20true%0A1%2F1%20-%3E%20true%0A12%2F19%20-%3E%20false%0A5%2F17%20-%3E%20false%0A3%2F5%20-%3E%20false%0A1%2F7%20-%3E%20false%0A1%2F2%20-%3E%20false%0A1%2F3%20-%3E%20true%0A2%2F3%20-%3E%20true)

This is an anonymous block (function) which takes two arguments on the stack and leaves `0` or `1` on the stack. It works by base converting the fraction `x/y` into `y` base `3` digits and returning true iff they contain no `1` or the only `1` is part of a suffix `1 0 0 0 ...`.

```
{            e# Begin a block
  _@3@#*\/3b e#   Base conversion
   0-W<      e#   Remove all zeros and the final non-zero digit
   1&!       e#   True iff no 1s are left
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
gu*3hS,G-QGQE0
```

Based on my C solution. `y` on first input line, `x` on second.

```
                Q = y
 u         QE   G = x
                loop y times
  *3                x = 3 *
    hS,G                min(x,
        -QG                 y-x)
g            0  return x >= 0
```

If `x/y` is within the Cantor set, `x` stays between `0` and `y`. Otherwise, `x` becomes greater than `y` at one point, then diverges to negative infinity in the remaining iterations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@59eqmWcEazjrhvoHuhq8P@/oTGXoQEA)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 91 bytes

```
@set/ai=%3+1,n=%1*3%%%2,f=%1*3/%2%%2,f^|=j=!((%2-i)*n)
@if %f%==0 %0 %n% %2 %i%
@echo %j%
```

Tests the first `y-1` base 3 digits of `x/y`. `i` is the count of digits tested. `n` is the next value of `x`. `j` is true if `n` reaches zero (because the expansion terminates) or we have tested `y-1` digits without finding a `1`. `f` is true if `j` is true or if the next digit is a `1`, at which point we stop looping and output `j`.