# Convert singular to plural

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

There are two forms of nouns, singular and plural. The conversion between these two is quite easy.

1. Normally, you end it with `s`. ex. `car` => `cars`.
2. If it ends with `s`,`x`,`z`,`ch` or `sh`, end it with `es`. ex. `bus`=>`buses`.
3. If it ends with `y` with a consonant just before it, change the `y` to `ies`. ex. `penny` => `pennies`.
4. If it ends with `f` or `fe`, change it to `ves`. ex. `knife` => `knives`.
5. If it ends with `o` with a consonant just before it, change it to `oes`. ex.`potato` => `potatoes`.

---

## Task

You will be given a singular noun. You have to convert the given noun to plural and output it.

---

## Rules

- You will not be given irregular nouns, like `mouse` and `moose`.
- You will not be given exceptions, such as `safe` (`safes`; violating #4), `piano` (`pianos`; violating #5) and `o` (`oes`, violating #5).
- You will not be given words which have two or more possible plural forms, such as `mosquito` (`mosquitos` or `mosquitoes`) and `roof` (`roofs` or `rooves`).
- You will not be given uncountable nouns.
- `y` doesn't count as a vowel.

---

## Examples

```
car => cars
bus => buses
potato => potatoes
knife => knives
penny => pennies
exception => exceptions
wolf => wolves
eye => eyes
decoy => decoys
radio => radios
```

Comment: Edited question for clarity. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: Ahh, English - a huge pile of arbitrary rules and special cases :)

Comment: @Challenger5 Yep, but you can understand it through tough thorough thoughts, though. ;)

Comment: @MatthewRoh I've edited the consonant in front rule to make it clearer. Also added a couple of test cases for the same. If I've misunderstood, please edit it to clarify.

Comment: Do we need to handle `o` => `os` or `oes`?

Comment: @DLosc It's stated in Rule 5. o=>oes.

Comment: @Challenger5 If you compare English to Dutch there are barely any rules at all.. Dutch has rules and special cases, and special cases contradicting those special cases, and in some cases even special cases that contradict those special cases that those special cases contradict. ;)

Comment: I guess excluding proper nouns?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you guys should see French...

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, French is a pain as well.. ;) I was glad I could drop the subject when I went to the fourth class in high school.. Always had around a 5 for French and German.. I kinda suck with languages (although I had an 8 for Dutch and English classes..) Ah, the memories.. XD

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
Pluralize
```

Yes, there is a built-in for this!

**Sample output**

```
Pluralize["car"]
```

> `cars`

```
Pluralize /@ {"bus", "potato", "knife", "penny", "exception", "wolf", "eye"}
```

> `{"buses", "potatoes", "knives", "pennies", "exceptions", "wolves", "eyes"}`

Comment: Waaaaaat! Is there something Mathematica has no built-in for?

Comment: D: Builtins have attacked this challenge too

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/56033

Answer (score 19):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>57</s> <s>53</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

*Thanks to MartinEnder for some golfing suggestions*

*Thanks to BusinessCat for golfing 1 byte*

```
([^aeiou]o|sh?|ch|z|x)$
$1e
fe?$
ve
([^aeiou])y$
$1ie
$
s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#PcoxDsIwEETRfs5hpKTkBCk5BAJhNhPZirRrYQfFke9uoKH41fun4fLow/XuGW27WcthahLa0fbRwZ2JhZPDm/g/Y/1BJBxy7@JfeG4Zs@nKilXjQiQrvhgSVSu4C1OJpmAl5m9iXsIH)

#### Explanation (outdated)

```
([^aeiou])y$
$1ie
```

Changes `{consonant}y` to `{consonant}ie`

```
([^aeiou]o|[fxzs]|[sc]h)$
$&e
```

Appends an `e` to when the word ends with an `{consonant}o`, `f`,`x`,`z`,`s`,`sh` or `ch`.

```
fe$
ve
```

Changes an ending `fe` to `ve`

```
$
s
```

Finally append an `s` to the word.

#### Edits

- Added bytes because I forgot the second rule
- Added bytes to update with `eye` as an example

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've not used Retina. Why are the round brackets needed in the first line?

Comment: Never mind, I think I've answered my own question. It's because of the lookback reference in the following line.

Comment: Yeah, it's because we want to capture the character before the `y` using `$1`

Comment: I think I got it in 57 bytes: [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@69RnGFfk5xRU1VTURMdl5iamV8am6@pwqVimMqVlmqvwlWWyqUBk9CsBElkpnKpcBX//59amQoA)

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>109</s>  97 bytes

```js
s=>s[R='replace'](/([^aeiou])y$/,'$1ie')[R](/fe?$/,'ve')[R](/([^aeiou]o|[sxz]|[cs]h)$/,'$1e')+'s'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDRbsIgFIDhe5@iMSaUzK3x2tS9g7ekSxg9KNpwmp5a7eK7dyhbNT1yx88HAQ6602QaV7fvHksYbD5QviG1zUUDdaUNiCLNUvWlweGpkP0iW4rFyoGQahtWLHzeSvc/HyVeFV1@iqsyVOxl3BXQmyAxGPSEFXxUuEttOje6mUu5Tv5GliX5JgmRZhP4fSIOQwQma2x1iyOOMkaOj95ZeBwccYjdi3PB@35Kb9FxCxcDdevQRx/tGBk/Y2WfXhd5iC9uAT3wfwiRwRIMsuveI6ONLh1O6T3S8As)

Comment: Why do you have a `()` in front of `fe`?

Comment: @KodosJohnson All `replace()` iterations include a reference to the first matching group (with `$1`). That's why I need an empty matching group here.

Comment: Have you tried `(?<![aeiou])y`?

Comment: @Titus Unfortunately, JS doesn't implement lookbehind assertions.

Answer (score 11):

### Batch, 325 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@for %%v in (a e i o u)do @(
for %%e in (o y)do @if %s:~-2%==%%v%%e goto s
if %s:~-2%==%%vf set s=%s:~,-1%ve&goto s
if %s:~-3%==%%vfe set s=%s:~,-2%ve&goto s
)
@if %s:~-1%==y set s=%s:~,-1%ie
@for %%e in (o s x z)do @if %s:~-1%==%%e set s=%s%e
@for %%e in (c s)do @if %s:~-2%==%%eh set s=%s%e
:s
@echo %s%s
```

Comment: What about `@echo off` at the beginning rather than `@` everywhere? Also, `@set/ps=` seems a little bit rusty from a phone. Won't the `s` variable accept the slicing values anyway?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr `@echo off` is already 9 bytes without the newline, so it doesn't save me anything. Also, `@set/ps=` is needed to input the value in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, <strike>216</strike> <strike>207</strike> 205 bytes

Thanks to @Lynn, @user1472751 and @Laikoni for the help!

```
import Data.List
(!)s=or.map(\x->x`isSuffixOf`s)
c=['b'..'z']\\"eiou"
p s|s!(words"s x z ch sh"++map(:"o")c)=s++"es"|s!map(:"y")c=init s++"ies"|s!["f"]=init s++"ves"|s!["fe"]=(init.init)s++"ves"|0<1=s++"s"
```

### Readable

```
import Data.List;

endsWithOneOf :: String -> [String] -> Bool
endsWithOneOf str ends = (or . map (\end -> end `isSuffixOf` str)) ends 

consonants :: [Char]
consonants = ['a'..'z'] \\ "aeiou"

pluralize :: String -> String
pluralize str
    | str `endsWithOneOf` (words "s x z ch sh" ++ (map (:"o") consonants)) = str ++ "es"
    | str `endsWithOneOf` (map (:"y") consonants) = init str ++ "ies"
    | str `endsWithOneOf` ["f"] = init str ++ "ves"
    | str `endsWithOneOf` ["fe"] = (init.init) str ++ "ves"
    | otherwise = str ++ "s"
```

### Explanation

`import Data.List` for the function `isSuffixOf`.
`endsWithOneOf` (`€` in the golfed version) returns whether one of the list elements is an ending of the string.
`consonants(c)` is just a list of all consonants.

Finally, `pluralize(p)` checks for the endings and returns the proper pluralization.

Example:

```
p "potato" == "potatoes"
```

Comment: Nice solution!

This is 216 *characters*, but `€` is multiple bytes long, making your solution 226 bytes. (Code golf challenges are explicitly scored in bytes, because counting characters lets you cheat sometimes.) You can just rename it to `!`, though!

Also, `words"s x z ch sh"` saves 5 bytes. Removing parens around `(map(:"o")c))` and `(map(:"y")c))` saves 4 more.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Lynn! I implemented your suggestions.

Comment: You can save one byte by using `c=['b'..'z']\\"eiou"` since `'a'` is always removed.

Comment: `0<1` is one byte shorter than `True`. Also newlines are the same byte count as `;` but make the golfed code a bit better readable.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>103</s> 100 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace(['/([^aeiou]o|sh?|x|z|ch)$/','/(?<![aeiou])y$/','/fe?$/'],['\1e',ie,ve],$argv[1]).s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JclbCoAgEEDRtQSBCUPRd4YLmSwkJhUCxR5UuHcL@rvck4XsQyQzRQqrnqlC1lQ4anL@UD5tVqYrPWm2vGwYfCZFgb/y@18LyS8UIBtaYuAITlJQ6mhObBWvty7nHPyud/8C)

The `preg_replace` function takes in an array of patterns and replacements.

- Saved 2 bytes thanks to Titus.
- Saved 1 byte thanks to Dewi Morgan.

Comment: I think You can save one byte with `-R` and `$argn`. And using an assertion with `y` saves two: `(?<![aeiou])y$` allows `ie` as replacement: no  `\1`, no quotes.

Comment: Another byte from `([^aeiou]o|sh?|x|z|ch)$`

Comment: @Titus Actually it looks like there is a [1 byte penalty for using `-R` (but not `-r`)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2428/40638) so that doesn't change the byte count, unfortunately. But the lookbehind suggestion works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 80 bytes

```
f&s{s~="([^aeiou])y$","$1ie","([sxz]|[cs]h|[^aeiuo]o)$","$1e","fe?$","ve"s.="s"}
```

The function modifies its argument. Usage: `main word { f word; print word }` Here's a version that uses a return value (83 bytes):

```
f s{s~="([^aeiou])y$","$1ie","([sxz]|[cs]h|[^aeiuo]o)$","$1e","fe?$","ve";[s.."s"]}
```

And below is a function that reads infinitely many values from the input stream and pushes plural forms to the output stream (<s>87</s> 83 bytes):

```
{replace"([^aeiou])y$","$1ie","([sxz]|[cs]h|[^aeiuo]o)$","$1e","fe?$","ve","$","s"}
```

It's an anonymous function, as that is shorter than creating a named function.

Comment: How do you get to display the result of the first function (the one starting with `f&s`)? Simply `f("word")` doesn't seem to display anything

Comment: @KritixiLithos The parameter is a reference, so the argument must be a variable.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 66 + 2 (`-pl` flag) = 68 bytes

```
$_.=/(ch|sh?|x|z|[^aeiou]o)$/+s/([^aeiou])y$/$1i/+s/fe?$/v/?es:"s"
```

Using:

```
perl -ple '$_.=/(ch|sh?|x|z|[^aeiou]o)$/+s/([^aeiou])y$/$1i/+s/fe?$/v/?es:"s"' <<< car
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/LIMaEo)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>271</s> <s>239</s> 199 bytes

Thanks to @ovs for reducing it by 72 bytes!

```
lambda s,v="aeiou":(s[-2:]=="fe"and s[:-2]+"ve"or s[:-1]+((s[-1]=="y"and s[-2]not in v)*"ie"or s[-1]=="f"and"ve"or s[-1]+((s[-1]in"sxz"or s[-2:]in["ch","sh"])+(s[-1]=="o"and s[-2]not in v))*"e"))+"s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bY/BbsIwDIbP21NE/ylZyyQ4Viov0uUQ2kRYg7hqQkdBPHtJugrtsJPtX5/9ya7@mk/mfOiMCOVYw1jiCyoZms2u0nUNZ2F8J0JTbXa6wGjBwzJtdSEzts3UtEKJ8RwFeTGqD9AK/zIuM68Df/bJI1xva5ys5Bu0R5QIR2hVvCT8jyRZLJQqEDC7dIFynNbNgFLgcAm59BxN5Nx9e0oP5ch6P@XGXlvbR2Kfhx8@uSWcFqizLS/QYDpi6Or9rR/IR4n7Q9R7cX/gM0nPJkoqnSSl1PwE)

Comment: You can remove some unnecessary whitespaces and combine the first and last `elif`. The single character lists can be replaced by strings. Switching to python saves additional 3 bytes. [tio](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#TY5BCoMwEEX3nkL@StEu6jKQk4gLsSMOlIk4UWwvn8ZQW3f5vPeYBK03yzKvvihr9MRuRcZjru3t3rFA9zfccszGxN1imFBDJ3RGKwtSZPSMfpECa/H66mk4lL08Ut2J8zlLvhm12prIK/AvP4MRF7xdcTx/cDqF5i8opb/E97yw@ELLEGgfaPbs5AM)

Comment: @ovs Done, thanks! I didn't combine the `elif`s however, because that means `potato` becomes `potaties`.

Comment: I looked in the wrong line ;). You can combine the if with the last elif. To save some more bytes replace the last line with `print(s+"s")` and remove the else case as well every s you are appending to the word. [Tio](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#Zc6xCoMwFIXh3acIZ0rQDnUM5EnEQdqIF0puyI1S@/I2lbZIOx6@fzibNIujEOesTYPBE8@oaNTSnc49Bcj9AU6qzNaW3eEyoYFM6A0nrfbMOTCGcN2rPnBWFNRirNQOHpW/0fgN1//QipPOFq5Bv/mIgy4HLW9e7D/evj0mCllLDYHZtsh5yPwE)

Comment: When you replace your if/elif logic with `and/*` and `or/+` and make an unnamed lambda function you can get it [under 200 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bY/BbsIwDIbP21NE/ylZyyQ4Viov0uUQ2kRYg7hqQkdBPHtJugrtsJPtX5/9ya7@mk/mfOiMCOVYw1jiCyoZms2u0nUNZ2F8J0JTbXa6wGjBwzJtdSEzts3UtEKJ8RwFeTGqD9AK/zIuM68Df/bJI1xva5ys5Bu0R5QIR2hVvCT8jyRZLJQqEDC7dIFynNbNgFLgcAm59BxN5Nx9e0oP5ch6P@XGXlvbR2Kfhx8@uSWcFqizLS/QYDpi6Or9rR/IR4n7Q9R7cX/gM0nPJkoqnSSl1PwE) (I swapped the cases a little bit)

Comment: @ovs Ooh, that `print(s+"s")` is clever. All changed; you pretty much rewrote the whole thing lol. Thanks! (I didn't even know you could do `True and "string"` like that)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>131</s> <s>125</s> <s>118</s> 121 bytes

*Thanks to [The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu) for -6 bytes!
Golfed 7 bytes!
Fixed an issue for +3 bytes!*

```python
lambda x:S("([sc]h?|x|z)$","\\1e",S(V+"y$","ie",S("fe?$","ve",S(V+"o$","oe",x))))+"s"
import re;S,V=re.sub,"(?<![aeiou])"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclBTsMwEEDRPacYRixs1VRC7Aohh4jUTdOFk4zVUVOPZTskRr17aJD4u6cfSr6If19d1a6jvXWDheXQKFSn1J8v9X25/@gXNNi2b4SmUccdls38J3RUb/r@f7JJHlr0ox0mfOJbkJgh0kdjjlWkfZo6g6r@fD5ZYpnOGlcnEWZgD9jbCN2UIEi2WeDq2REE8r4ALT2FzOJhltEBFYKBeikQ7cCC@xRGzkofQmSf1WycmrVJFCqE1y9Avf4C)

My first submission on here! Let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to code golf! Very impressive first answer!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and amazing first answer! You can save 5 bytes by assigning `re.sub` to a variable: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYpBbsIwEADvfcVq1YOtBqSql4oq8AiODZWcZC1WBO/Kdpq44u8pLZyY48xoyUcJb@8aF183y@DObe9g3uwNms/UHY67y3z5sc9YYdO8Elb/4csRy3iw5e75Fjzt/sT34yb3Ta5htldeMOETn1Vihkgf@zrSOo3t4iXCBBwAOxehHROoZJcFToE9gVIIBWjuSDNLgEkGD1QIeuqkQHQ9C66TDpyN3WjkkM1UeTPZKpHWCKstoF1@AQ)

Comment: And you can save another one by assigning the regex for a consonant to a variable: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BasMwEEX3PcUwZCERNVC6KSluDmHIpk5BtkdkiKMRkhxbJXd33ZL@3Xtv8UPJZ/GvbyEurmqWwV7b3sK8rxWqz9Sdzof7fP/WGzTYNC@EplbHLZYH859AR4dfcfvP8siyilmv22LCJ74GiRkivdfmWEXapbE168uXJZbxpHFxEmEC9oCdjdCOCYJkmwUunh1BIO8L0NxRyCweJhkcUCHoqZMC0fYsuEth4Kz0PkT2WU3GqUmbRKFCeP4A1MsP)

Comment: @The Thonnu Thanks a lot!

Comment: @lyxal Thank you!

Comment: All of the replacements end with e, there has to be some way to golf that...

Answer (score 3):

## sed, 70 <s>79</s> bytes

69 <s>78</s> + 1 for `-E` (BSD)/`-r` (GNU) flag

```
s/([^aeiou])y$/\1ie/
s/([^aeiou]o|[fxzs]|[sc]h)$/&e/
s/fe/ve/
s/$/s/
```

Direct port of the [retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112080/).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```
Y`[^aeiou]`OaR[C`sh?|x|z|ch`Cy.'y`fe?`y.'o].'$[_B.'i'v_].'e's
```

*So close* to catching Retina! But it's probably not going to happen. :(

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#JYpBDoIwFET3nqIhJtUNVyCRxK3GnWmQfsuvNGJLoChFPDv@hs28mZc5gkgUdAlL7kO/Zk3QZpoIHkbKZrAqyhc8jFqtIbTOg3dUntZojAKtDUQcFbbeOEv94xodVYiHCpWLhw4q45Jiw85s912uUtwAjRsKeYKLyGVfZ/M4T7OqZR5SHqTGTFJxRcq3ojyk3PB3SQN5v7Afg/3yBw)

#### Explanation

Basic strategy: `R`eplace performs several replacements one after the other when given lists of patterns and replacements. We want to make the following replacements:

- `(sh?|x|z|ch)$` -> add an `e`
- `[^aeiou]y` -> change the `y` to `i` and add an `e`
- `fe?` -> change to `v` and add an `e`
- `[^aeiou]o` -> add an `e`

Then we want to tack on an `s` regardless.

Tricks:

- The `C` operator, given a regex, wraps it in a capturing group; `` C`xyz` `` is one byte shorter than `` `(xyz)` ``.
- A list of regexes or replacements that all end with the same character can be created by concatenating the character to the list instead of including it in all the items. Concatenating a Scalar (string) to a Pattern (regex/replacement) coerces to a Pattern.
- Instead of concatenating the `s` (and having to deal with the precedence ordering of `R` and `.`), we can simply `O`utput the main part of the word and then print the `s` separately.

Spaced and commented code:

```
                  a is 1st cmdline input (implicit)
Y`[^aeiou]`       Yank the consonant regex into the y variable
O a R             Output (without newline): a, with the following replacements:
 [                List of regexes to replace:
  C `sh?|x|z|ch`    (sh?|x|z|ch)
  Cy . 'y           ([^aeiou])y
  `fe?`             fe?
  y . 'o            [^aeiou]o
 ] . '$           End of list; concatenate $ to each item
 [                List of replacements:
  _                 Identity function (replace with whole match)
  B                 B is short for {b}, a function returning its second argument; as a
                    callback function for regex replacement, the second argument is
                    the value of capturing group 1 (the consonant before y)
    . 'i            To that, concatenate i
  'v                Scalar literal v
  _                 Identity function
 ] . 'e           End of list; concatenate e to each item
's                Return Scalar literal s, which is autoprinted
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>73</s> 163 bytes:

```
Func<string,string>p=System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Pluralize
```

Yes, another language with it built-in (although you need to add a reference to `System.Data.Entity.Design.dll`)

To use:

```
var words = new[] { "car", "bus", "potato", "knife", "penny", "exception", "wolf", "eye", "decoy", "radio" };
foreach (var word in words)
{
    var plural = p(word);
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"{word} => {plural}");
}
```

Output:

> ```
> car => cars
> bus => buses
> potato => potatoes
> knife => knives
> penny => pennies
> exception => exceptions
> wolf => wolves
> eye => eyes
> decoy => decoys
> radio => radios
> ```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  How do I run this code?

Comment: @WheatWizard updated.  Should I have included more detail (using statements etc) in the byte count?

Comment: Interesting bit of trivia, the reverse of this (Singularize) fails quite a few simple test cases. For example, it's convinced the singular of "courses" is "cours".

Comment: I think the namespaces needs to be included in this one's byte count, *especially* given that it's not one of the 'normal' ones. But I think you also need to at least wrap this in a lambda, passing the argument to the method. As is this is just a method group

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 better now?

Answer (score 2):

## Python <s>199</s> <s>187</s> 176 Bytes

```
lambda s:s+'\bve'*(s[-1]=='f')+'\b\bve'*(s[-2:]=='fe')+'e'*(s[-1]in'sxz'or s[-2:]in('ch','sh')or s[-1]=='o'and s[-2]not in'aiueo')+'\bie'*(s[-1]=='y'and s[-2]not in'aiueo')+'s'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Rails runner, 18 bytes

```
$><<gets.pluralize
```

Example:

```
$ echo knife | rails r filename.rb
knives
```

Comment: Now that's an esoteric language.

Answer (score 1):

**Python,** **296** **bytes**

```
z = input()
if z[-1]in['s','x','z','ch','sh']:print(z+'es')
elif z[-1]=='y'and z[-2]not in['a','e','i','o','u']:print(z[:-1]+'ies')
elif z[-2:]=='fe':print(z[:-2]+'ves')
elif z[-1]=='f':print(z[:-1]+'ves')
elif z[-1]=='o'and z[-2]not in['a','e','i','o','u']:print(z[:-1]+'oes')
else:print(z+'s')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 102 bytes

```bash
Class v {a,e,i,o,u}
p:
*=>es/{s,x,z,ch,zh,!@v o} _ $
y=>ies/!@v _ $
f e?=>ves/_ $
Else:
*=>s/_ $
```

Ungolfed explanation:

```bash
# define vowels
Class vowel {a,e,i,o,u}

plural:
*=>es/{s,x,z,ch,zh,!@vowel o} _ $ # 2,5
y=>ies/!@vowel _ $                # 3
{f,fe}=>ves/_ $                   # 4
Else:                             # Run the rules below if the above rules don't apply
*=>s/_ $                          # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java 7, 408 bytes

**Golfed:**

```
boolean b="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzs".contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length()-2))); String x=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);if(s.endsWith("s")||s.endsWith("x")||s.endsWith("z")||s.endsWith("ch")||s.endsWith("sh"))return s+"es";if(s.endsWith("y")&&b)return x+"ies";if(s.endsWith("f")) return x+"ves";if(s.endsWith("fe"))return s.substring(0,s.length()-2)+"ves";if(s.endsWith("o")&&b)return s+"es";return s+="s";
```

Basically testing what the end of the String is and adding / replacing letters depending on what case it is. The boolean and String at the beginning are just for removing repetition in the test cases and making the code smaller.

**Readable version:**

```
public static String pluralize(String s){

// Consonant at the 2nd last position?
boolean b = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzs".contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length()-2))); 

// Substring for cases where last letter needs to be replaced
String x = s.substring(0,s.length()-1);

if(s.endsWith("s") || s.endsWith("x") || s.endsWith("z") || s.endsWith("ch") || s.endsWith("sh"))
    return s + "es";
if(s.endsWith("y") && b)
    return x + "ies";
if(s.endsWith("f")) 
    return x + "ves";
if(s.endsWith("fe"))
    return s.substring(0,s.length()-2) + "ves";
if(s.endsWith("o") && b)
    return s + "es";

return s += "s";
}
```

Comment: You can't use a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 321 bytes

```
#define E else if(
#define C unsigned char
C*p(C*b){static C r[999],i,w,n,m;for(n=w=i=0;r[i]=b[i];n=w,w=b[i++]);m=!strchr("aeiou",n);if(strchr("sxz",w)||(w=='h'&&strchr("cs",n))||(w=='o'&&m))r[i++]='e';E'y'==w&&m)r[i-1]='i',r[i++]='e';E'f'==w)r[i-1]='v',r[i++]='e';E'f'==n&&w=='e')r[i-2]='v';r[i++]='s';r[i]=0;return r;}
```

test:

```
C*mx[]={"car","bus","potato","knife","penny","exception","wolf","eye","decoy","radio",0};

main()
{unsigned i;
 for(i=0;mx[i];++i)
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", mx[i], p(mx[i]));
 return 0;
}
```

results:

```
[car] [cars]
[bus] [buses]
[potato] [potatoes]
[knife] [knives]
[penny] [pennies]
[exception] [exceptions]
[wolf] [wolves]
[eye] [eyes]
[decoy] [decoys]
[radio] [radios]
[radio] [radios]
```

Comment: It should be `wolves` not `wolfves`.

Comment: @ceilingcat what about "static C r[256],/*Z="aeiou",i=0,w,n;" in the place of "static C r[256];C/*Z="aeiou",i=0,w,n;"?

Comment: [260 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZDBbsIwDIbvfQovE6SlqaDs1GUVmvoCSBxZDyWkYG0kVVJWGPDsLKFj03zw/@uz5cQWyUaI6/VxLWtUEhZgWyOaY2hiDO6wgL2yuFFyDWJbmaAYNWExWkUn21YtClc3yyzLSoasY4rteK1NiPmEmyWW@col3nmJ4zJSecd3uX9ka0JSSdR7wlTEH@7IHr4I66LhsEvolp5DlWTZcKgSamkPNT3vZvRIk85r7fSW1dnVJJ0tGLEkel4kU0Y@ZW/TfxZ7y4hXbmS7NwoMv1wLGFXGtssyPxFRGcLIam9dbrTbUzvzrrCWHkiljk7lQcimRa2c7/RH7dHRN6yl0L7BVGvU5MJ/TzmHxqBq6yAYj9N04iKFPAdaUQCPJn/olToAPfEAnqbBrkIVRgGcCoDRigcAbhggD5y7Hx1f0gmPY3Rtt5iHZGBhYN/cL@G2H5YMmvDHRpEbc7l@Aw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

Direct port of Retina:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 111 bytes

```ruby
'sub(/([^aeiou])y/){"#{$1}ie"};sub(/(.*)([^aeiou]o|[fxzs]|[sc]h)$/){"#{$1}#{$2}e"};sub(/fe/,"ve");sub(/$/,"s")'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X724NElDXyM6LjE1M780VrNSX7NaSblaxbA2M1Wp1hoiq6elCVeRXxOdVlFVHFsTXZwcm6GpAlcPJIxq4XrSUvV1lMpSlTQhXBUgr1hJU/3/f67///ILSjLz84r/6@YUpAIA)

Invoke via `ruby -lpe` and supply a file as `input.txt` for first CLI argument.

Comment: Can probably be more 'golfed'. Btw.: Can one add files to TIO?