# Is it a bird, is it a plane?

Tags: decision-problem, image-processing, test-battery

### Challenge

Supplied an image, you must determine if the subject of the image is a bird or a plane.

If the image is a bird, your program must output

```
bird
```

and if the image is a plane, your program must output

```
plane
```

Your program must produce no other output and the testing program will be case sensitive.

### Further information

All images will be the objects in flight.

The images of planes and birds will be against blue backgrounds (in some there may be light cloud in patches).

All birds will be pictured gliding from underneath, with their wings spread open. They will not always be the same species.

All planes will be commercial jetliners, pictured from the side. Their liveries may differ and the models will not be the same.

You may not use any external libraries, functions or online resources which perform image recognition.

The images will not be revealed to the competitors.

### Examples

The following examples will ***not*** be used in the 30 test images.

#### Birds

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

### Planes

[image]
[image]

### Winning

Given 60 images of birds and planes, the program which identifies the most of then correctly wins.

In case of a tie, first post wins.

#### Note:

Thank you to Beta Decay for writing this challenge! Beta allowed me to take it and post. [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/5648#5648)

Comment: Hello, I will not be on until ~11 EST so please be patient with questions.

Comment: I think this problem is too complicated for a code golf. But good luck.

Comment: @hucancode This is not code golf. Also if you think that look of the Game Of life Clock

Comment: An airplane looks surprisingly much like a bird flying sideways.

Comment: @hucancode I would tend to agree with you. But then I remember [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71631/36398) (and specially the Mathematica answer)

Comment: Not really a good idea to post a challenge when you can't answer any questions about it. I like the challenge, but I think there is important information missing about what images we can expect. Specifically with regards to the birds. You say there can be different species, but you don't say anything about what species we might get. The differences between various types of birds are huge. I voted to close this for now, but I'm happy to retract that vote once you have clarified this. :)

Comment: What should the output be for [these](https://xkcd.com/1824/)? ;)

Comment: Since you took this from the sandbox without modification, do you even have the 30 test images?

Comment: @MartinEnder I am creating the list now. I will also ask beta about them

Comment: @StewieGriffin I will crop the images so they almost fit the box as said. but they will not always stretch one way. The planes will always be horizontal as I need images from the side

Comment: For later reference: There's a reason why those challenges are where they are. Most need some substantial improvement to be made into full challenges, and it's best to try to work that out _before_ you post.

Comment: You should already have the 30 images before creating the challenge, and provide a way to prove that you already do (hash of a zip archive or something). Also, I don't think 30 is enough. As it is, luck will probably play a factor in picking a winner.

Comment: @Dennis I will work on that. 60 images?

Comment: The more the merrier.

Comment: @Dennis sounds good!

Comment: Shortest code as a tie-breaker in a code-challenge is [not a great idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8195/31516). Also, I'm sure most will get (close to) 100% success-rate. Two parallel lines are easy to detect, and if those aren't present then you can go for the windows (small boxes on a straight row). If there are airplanes that don't have the same shape as the ones in the picture then you should inform about this and show an example.