# I'm in your subnets, golfing your code

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, networking

#### Challenge

Given an IPv4 `address` in dotted-quad notation, and an IPv4 `subnet` in [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks), determine if the `address` is in the `subnet`. Output a distinct and consistent value if it is in the `subnet`, and a separate distinct and consistent value if it is not in the `subnet`. The output values do not necessarily need to be truthy/falsey in your language.

#### CIDR subnet notation brief primer

IPv4 network addresses are 32 bits in length, split into four groups of 8 bits for ease of reading. CIDR subnet notation is a ***mask*** of the specified number of bits, starting leftmost. For example, for a `/24` subnet, this means the right-most 8 bits of the address are available in that subnet. Thus two addresses that are separated by at most `255`, and have the same subnet mask, are in the same subnet. Note that valid CIDR have all the host-bits (the right hand side) unset (zeros).

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 00000000
^---    subnet mask   ---^ ^-hosts-^
```

For another example, a `/32` subnet specifies that *all* of the bits are the subnet mask, essentially meaning that only one host is allowed per `/32`.

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
^---        subnet mask        ---^
```

#### Examples:

Using `True` for "in the subnet" and `False` for "not in the subnet" as output:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.0/24
True

127.0.0.55
127.0.0.0/23
True

127.0.1.55
127.0.0.0/23
True

10.4.1.33
10.4.0.0/16
True

255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0/0
True

127.1.2.3
127.0.0.0/24
False

127.1.2.3
127.1.2.1/32
False

10.10.83.255
10.10.84.0/22
False
```

#### Rules and Clarifications

- Since input parsing isn't the interesting point of this challenge, you're guaranteed to get valid IPv4 addresses and subnet masks.
- Input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print the result to STDOUT or return it as a function result. Please state in your submission what values the output can take.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Do we have to take input in the same format as your test cases?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance You don't have to take them as one-per-line as in the examples, but you do need to take them as a dotted-quad and dotted-subnet as in the examples. (e.g., see the JavaScript answer by Arnauld)

Comment: Is it ok to have them separated by a slash, e.g. `10.0.0.1/10.0.0.0”/16`?

Comment: @NickKennedy (I'm presuming that the `"` is unintentional) Sure, separating by `/` is fine.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork yes typo. Thanks

Comment: I would argue that `1.255.1.1/8` _is_ a valid CIDR subnet but it requires more work to get the netmask. I don't think that's restricted anywhere and most tooling with subnets will do this normalization for you. If that's something we're marking as "not needed for this challenge", that's fine.

Comment: @Poke I agree you are correct in that CIDR notation describes an IP address and a subnet size.  As in, `1.255.1.1/8` is a valid CIDR *expression*, representing the host `1.255.1.1` within the network `1.0.0.0` with a subnet mask of `255.0.0.0`. However the challenge asks for the network *number* and subnet specifically in CIDR notation, which `1.255.1.1/8` is not a valid network number and subnet combination.

Comment: Now we also need an IPv6 version of this challenge

Comment: Your 2 separate values output requirement excludes 0 vs. non-zero.  Is that intentional?  In some languages, like C or asm, it's more convenient to return any non-zero integer as "truthy".  e.g. for this problem `(host ^ mask) >> (32 - bits)` to shift out the host part, leaving zero iff the host matches the network part of the mask.  (Modulo handling bits=0)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, that's intentional. People tend to complain a lot about truthy-vs-falsey challenges, so that's the best compromise I've come up with.

Comment: Ok, well for some languages it's the opposite of helpful, but that's fine as long as you're aware of the consequences.  Some real functions do have to booleanize their output to 0 or 1 instead of 0 / non-zero.

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3 (62 bytes)

Very straightforward:

```python
from ipaddress import*
lambda i,m:ip_address(i)in ip_network(m)
```

Comment: Nice, but does python have [a built-in for recognizing goats](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/84303) as well?

Comment: Of course Mathematica has a build-in for everything - [even for exoplanets](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Exoplanet.html)! Nothing can beat that... But as you could have seen, [Python matches Mathematica's goat-formace](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165194/32381)

Comment: I wonder if does a `ip_adress` object and a `ip_network` object constitute `any convenient method`, possibly letting Python win, unless a python-based golfing language has these as its types?

Comment: You won't get it in the range of 20 bytes in normal Python. Only the import and lambda are already longer than the Stax answer. It's no surprise that golfing languages win from "normal" languages... :-(

Comment: @someone: I beat Python with [53 bytes of x86-64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code/185097#185097).  :) Not a traditional golfing language, and most of the code-size is parsing string->int manually.  `(host^net)>>(32-mask)` is only 10 bytes.  But it's half way in between for tasks not involving lists of lists, or mapping a function onto a list, because many scalar operations can be done with a 2 or 3 byte instruction, and loops can be constructed around things in a few bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 250+31=281 bytes

```cs
(a,b)=>{Func<string,string>h=g=>string.Join("",g.Split('.').Select(x=>{var e=Convert.ToString(int.Parse(x),2);while(e.Length<8)e='0'+e;return e;}));a=h(a);var c=b.Split('/');b=h(c[0]);var d=int.Parse(c[1]);return a.Substring(0,d)==b.Substring(0,d);};
```

*Bytecount includes `using System;using System.Linq;`*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTfa9swEH6u/4rDL7Gop9pJs5U5CozuB2wdFDK2h9IH2VESDU/qJDlNCf7bs5PtLA5bwxjGSL6777vzpzsV9kVhi11lpVrC7Mk68SPrf9AbqX5mQVCU3Fp4sw2s404W8L5SxcQ6g5Ex7Ndc63IKi0oB20U8zgmbbvuB7TJdsSWbtnv6UUsVhWG8pLOHUrpoQAeEzkQpChdtEL7mBgS71motjKNf9KyBRVI5esuNFdGGxEOSPa5kKSJBb4RautXkigg2SAbnIjPCVUaByGpCMs5WESeZ5yxYvs94MSBZjp7iLrlvnXN24C/uUrR2NJzOqrytPEriOWGe5ciS1dmuk6gT8FqX/m@kVpZ@EEoYWdC3sjFw89RJc3e/V88J6ywwUOLx/xgiAtvgbOvxe882TIevaIJPGsa/98nF8DKsY2cqUcfPIsbjY8joBCShlzSlo5FH@L0HpC@fBwzHY9p7EZZ0aZLThaV0SEd//sqCl/ZfIH6fXoyGpyCoVUKvRl1d3eelz3SABTVOxoORa@4EdKfeUoC55fNI59/x3EDHgP0EsjmYzo8LHrI@dDTJgrO2i9HV9TFMPMiHnjMIIcSQrhHRlgU1Jq/yskna5F5rOYfPHCfKp1poI3ixguhEG30ST195WYlbLs1fWxErb1uyKR7n0OpS0G9GOoE3Q1PsYYwhjKEvI2wbGTzeZ8L5itMxieHYmqL1Cq0hm3qC8N3mAcsU89dhP7IpMwYPD7maw1I79ONdc0QPPVbSE9dPP@pV17tf)

I wrote this in JS as soon as the challenge was posted, but Arnauld beat me to the punch with a much better answer, so here it is in C# instead.

Definitely a lot of room for golfing.

### Explanation:

The function consists of a sub-function called `h`:

```cs
h=g=>string.Join("",
    g.Split('.').Select(x => {
        var e = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(x), 2);
        while (e.Length < 8) e = '0' + e;
        return e;
    }
);
```

This sub-function splits the IP Address on `.`, converts each number to a binary string, left-pads each string with `0` to be 8 bits long, then concatenates the strings into one 32-bit binary string.

This is immediately done in-place with `a=h(a);` on the given IP Address.
We then split the Subnet mask into an IP Address and a mask number with `c=b.Split('/');`

The IP Address component is also passed through our sub-function: `b=h(c[0]);` and the mask number is parsed to an integer: `var d=int.Parse(c[1]);`

Finally we take the first `d` bits of both binary strings (where `d` is the mask number) and compare them: `return a.Substring(0,d)==b.Substring(0,d);`

Comment: Too tired to work this out so I just [Golfed yours for you](https://tio.run/##VY49a8MwEIb3/AqhxTrqKrY7tKCcoRQ6lAwFBzoYD7ZycQRGKrLyUYJ/u@s0CaHc9Bx37/Pq/lH3ZnzfWb3ogze2jdk/aJzr8pxtGI415g3mp33tmcZGFt@dCYLPOajzao3GBvlZ@56ELtMKlKew85YJjZYOZXWqY10m1SAL6kgH0WJ@kcgPZ6zgPG6vmZGM4HZ1vBoJ35zdkw9y5Yq/N3H3HSHOQB22piNBckm2DdvFCxBGSfRAtyKkBphyd81FK5J4PfHKvXpf/wiAqRziuboaRsVmsy9vAi2NJbERPM2eZTJNyuEOyTx74gDjLw "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: Actually forgot about PadLeft in that too [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xa8MwEIX3/AqhxXegKrY7NOBKEAodSoaCAx2MB1mWjcBIQZbTlJDf7jpNSyi33He8e@/p8UGPdn6dnH4eY7CuZ@QfNN4PUpKOiFkJ2Qh5PqpAtGh4eRhsBLqmWFxPrbAu8ncVRgO6ymosgolTcAS0cOazqs@K6SqtL7w0g9EReiFvIfzNWweUsv7XM@EJ/qlOQr54dzQh8r0vf/RwDzohy3HZ253pImxYkiaIy@/U3KwhZe3Ce78NQX0B4lJAiGu94jIXZLX6CDaanXUGOqBZ/sTTZTKKd0jX@SNFnL8B "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: Lots of optimizations. I'm happy to inform you that your `rPad` is a built-in on strings. [pastebin link to TIO link that is too long alone](https://pastebin.com/A2S5rkX9)

Comment: @someone Small FYI: URL shorteners like https://tinyurl.com/ are allowed in comments on this SE, unlike most. :)

Comment: 188 - https://tinyurl.com/y6xfkbxt - nice url shortening tips @KevinCruijssen

Comment: 184 :) https://tinyurl.com/y6qnx2cc

Answer (score 4):

## Linux POSIX shell (with net-tools/iputils) (34 bytes non-terminating, 47 bytes terminating)

What is best suited to parse network masks and addresses than the network utilities themselves? :)

```
route add -net $2 reject;! ping $1
```

**Warning:** the script is potentially damaging to your Internet connectivity, please run with care.

**Input:** the script takes the tested IP address as first argument, and the tested subnet. as second argument.

**Output:** the script returns a truthy value (0) if the first argument of the script belongs to the subnet indicated in the second argument. Otherwise, it will never terminate.

**Assumptions:** the script must be run as a root user, in a *clean* environment (*i.e.*, no other blackhole route has been set by the administrator, and if a previous instance of the script has been run, the blackhole route it created has been removed). The script also assumes a "working Internet connection" (*i.e.*, a valid default route is present).

---

### Explanation:

We create a *blackhole* route to the specified subnet. We then test connectivity to the provided IP address by using *ping*. If the address doesn't belong to the subnet (and since we assume a properly set Internet connection), *ping* will try to send packets to that address. Note that whether this address actually responds does not matter, as *ping* will keep trying forever. Conversely, if the address does belong to the subnet, *ping* will fail with **ENETUNREACH** and return 2, and since we negated the command, the script will succeed.

---

### Example

Test whether 5.5.5.5 belongs to 8.8.8.0/24

```
$ sudo ./a.sh 5.5.5.5 8.8.8.0/24
PING 5.5.5.5 (5.5.5.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
[...runs forever...]
```

(Clean with `sudo ip route del 8.8.8.0/24` after running the command).

Test whether 5.5.5.5 belongs to 5.5.5.0/24:

```
$ sudo ./a.sh 5.5.5.5 5.5.5.0/24
connect: Network is unreachable
$ echo $?
0
```

(Clean with `sudo ip route del 5.5.5.0/24` after running the command).

Test whether 8.8.8.8 belongs to 5.5.5.0/24:

```
$ sudo ./a.sh 8.8.8.8 5.5.5.0/24
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=2.27 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=1.95 ms
[...runs forever...]
```

(Clean with `sudo ip route del 5.5.5.0/24` after running the command).

---

## 47-byte version if we disallow non-terminating scripts

```
route add -net $2 reject;ping -c1 $1;[ $? = 2 ]
```

As per @Grimy's comment, here's the version which always terminates, and returns 0 (truthy) if the address is in the subnet, and 1 (falsy) otherwise. We make *ping* terminate with the `-c1` flag which limits the number of sent packets to 1. If the address responded, *ping* will return 0, and if not, ping will return 1. Only if the address belongs to the blackholed subnet will *ping* return 2, which is thus what we test against in the last command.

Comment: While clever, this doesn't meet the requirement to output a distinct and consistent value if the address is not in the subnet ([running forever doesn't count as an output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12317/6484), see also [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/6484)).

Comment: @Grimy: But it doesn't *silently* run forever, so only your 2nd link applies, not the first.  Also I think `ping` would die from SIGPIPE if it was running with stdout+stderr piped into another program, and the reader closed the pipe.  And that is the most likely use-case because the exit status can be success either way (if we added a `-c1` option to ping to set the count.)  But sure, reading its output with `var=$(/a.sh)` would fail; you'd need a reader that stopped after deciding, rather than reading the whole output and then looking at it.

Comment: @Grimy Fair point (although for the sake of the argument I could say that we have two consistent values here, since `ping` will terminate in less than, say, one second in case of a blackholed address). I added a terminating version for an extra 13 bytes! :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

Takes input as `(address)(subnet)`. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
a=>s=>!([s,v]=s.split`/`,+v&&(g=s=>s.split`.`.map(k=v=>k=k<<8|v)|k>>32-v)(a)^g(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdDdboIwFAfw@z2F40LaTE@/YPPC9tIn8A5daBwyBwNiWZMlvjtSQjO3hNmmF//T/HJyzoe22hzOp6ZdVvVb1h1lp6UyUj2ixCzsXhowTXlqU5Iunux8jnLZf/oipPCpG1RIK1Uhi/V6dbH4Uigl@NJipPFrjgzG3aGuTF1mUNY5CpPt@at9/96H@OG2fkQB4y9A@8sC/BMo4VGA8cwdQmY9zqZcHP@BYoRTjkIEDIQYmAtOsWffbsrxOIab5zQdW9LBevcLhrsq2ejSTE3OgIP4Z3Jns7vQBUYEvwv7NVNYCT/AmCPXdcAedlc)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>101</s> <s>92</s> 88 bytes

*-13 bytes from @gwaugh*

```php
function($i,$r){[$r,$n]=explode('/',$r);return(ip2long($i)&~(1<<32-$n)+1)==ip2long($r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDbisIwEIbv@xRFg0nYmubQ7i601TufwDtdRDS1hW4asq0Ioq9eG9EiskJlmIt/Zr456Uw38VRn2gVp0qS12lR5qRDIPWDwcQGMB9RPIg@6KLcSQR/aeGRkVRuFcs2LUu3aajw6IxbHgo@Bwh8MJ0mXa8tPTeQ4@7VZbetfjUCKIONfhLbGoOd2gvo8gBhHznBuaunITVa6g6UavILD8IkWvWhKAsKIEFfYCsuyzz4sD0Py4LYDvQ2nfTdnhBPx/9mzdfH3Dm0F8wXvR7ffpuRb3Be/6cDOf9VhOmku)

Comment: Had some fun golfing it (Ty!): `function($i,$r){return!((ip2long($i)^ip2long(strtok($r,'/')))>>32-strtok(_));}`

Comment: @Christoph very nice! Never occurred to me that you could just use any token for the second call to `strtok()`. Yours is 4 bytes shorter than my very similar answer below. Props!

Comment: @Christoph You should post your solution as a separated answer since it is better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

## PowerPC/PPC64 C, <del>116</del> 114 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){unsigned u[4];char*p=u;for(;p<u+3;)scanf("%hhu%c",p++,u+3);return!((*u^u[1])>>32-p[-4]);}
```

(Tested on x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04 using powerpc64-linux-gnu-gcc -static and qemu-user.)

The program takes the two lines on standard input, and as its exit code it returns 1 if the address matches and 0 if it does not.  (So this does depend on the specification not requiring a truthy value for a match and a falsey value for a mismatch.)  Note that if you're running interactively, you will need to signal EOF (`^D`) three times after entering the second line.

This relies on PowerPC being big-endian, and also on that platform returning 0 for right-shifting a 32-bit unsigned value by 32.  It reads the octets into unsigned values one-by-one, along with the netmask length in another byte; then it takes the xor of the two unsigned 32-bit addresses and shifts out the irrelevant bits.  Finally, it applies `!` to satisfy the requirement of returning only two distinct values.

Note: It *might* be possible to shave off two bytes by replacing `u+3` with `p` and requiring compilation with `-O0`.  That's living more dangerously than I care to, though.

Thanks to Peter Cordes for the inspiration for this solution.

---

## More portable C, <del>186</del> <del>171</del> 167 bytes

Here I'll preserve a more portable version which runs 167 bytes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){unsigned a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,n;scanf("%u.%u.%u.%u %u.%u.%u.%u/%u",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f,&g,&h,&n);return!(n&&((((a^e)<<8|b^f)<<8|c^g)<<8|d^h)>>32-n);}
```

This program takes the two lines on standard input, and returns exit code 1 if the address is in the subnet, and 0 if it isn't.  (So this does rely on the specification not requiring a truthy value for matches and a falsey value for non matches.)

A breakdown of the core expression:

- `a^e`, `b^f`, `c^g`, `d^h` calculates the xor of the address and the mask byte-by-byte.
- `(((a^e)<<8|b^f)<<8|c^g)<<8|d^h` then combines them into a single unsigned 32-bit value by a Horner-like method.
- `...>>32-n` then shifts off the bits of the xor difference that are not relevant to the subnet mask (keeping in mind that `-` has higher precedence in C than `<<`)
- There is one gotcha, though: if n=0 then `~0U<<32` will give undefined behavior assuming `unsigned` is 32 bits (which it is on virtually all current platforms).  On the other hand, if n=0 then any address will match, so `n&&...` will give the correct result (taking advantage of the short-circuiting behavior of `&&`).
- Finally, to meet the requirement that the output can only be one of two values, we apply `!` to output 0 or 1.

-15 bytes due to comments by ceilingcat and AdmBorkBork

-4 bytes due to comment by Peter Cordes

Comment: Using exit codes to return values is [one of the default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/42963) and is thus allowed.

Comment: @ceilingcat Of course, how silly of me to miss that.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork OK, thanks, I've changed it to use exit code.

Comment: idea: target a little-endian or big-endian C implementation (code-golf doesn't require portable code) and type-pun output pointers onto the bytes of an `unsigned`.  e.g. with `char*p=&a` then `p++,p++,p++,...` or `p--,...` as scanf args.  The format string would need to be `"%hhu.%hhu..."` though, so it's a significant tradeoff between that extra size vs. declaring fewer vars and being able to do `(a^b)>>(32-count)`

Comment: Can't you use `xor_result >> 32-count` to shift out the bits you don't want, instead of left-shifting a mask?  Heh, interesting `n&&...` trick to avoid UB by not evaluating an out-of-range shift count.  In practice, some platforms (like I think ARM) saturate the shift count (i.e. will shift out all the bits for count too large), but x86's scalar shift instructions mask the shift count with `&31`.  (Or `&63` for 64-bit shifts)  See [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](//stackoverflow.com/q/776508) for details.

Comment: So anyway, you might get away with `(...)>>32-count` on a C implementation targeting ARM, without the `n&&` part.  Code Golf rules say that it has to work on *some* implementation, not all.  (Some people stretch that as far as leaving out the `return` keyword for `gcc -O0`, but that just isn't even C anymore.)

Comment: In my [x86-64 machine-code answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code/185097#185097), I used `(host^net) >> (32-mask)` **using a 64-bit shift**.  If you cast to `long`, it should work for free on C implementations where `long` is 64-bit.  Or use `long long` for portability.  All your numbers end up much narrower than 64-bit, so they're definitely positive and thus no UB or weirdness for signed right shifts, but you can't just change your variables to `long` because the format string is for `unsigned int`. :/

Comment: @PeterCordes Yup, the right shift works, thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes With a loop of the type you were suggesting I did get an x86-64/x86 specific solution with 128 bytes.  (More specifically, it requires a little-endian platform which allows unaligned access to unsigned.)  It's significantly different, though, so I'm debating whether to post it as a separate answer or to completely replace the current one.

Comment: Oh good point, I might go separate answer if it's totally different.  Although separate sections of the same answer like you did here works, too.  Use a 2nd `# header` line for the portable version, though.  But unaligned access to `unsigned`?  I only see access to the bytes separately.  Every byte is always naturally aligned.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, my solution at that point had an array of 9 characters and then read out characters 1-4 and 5-8 as the `unsigned` values and character 0 as the netmask length.  Since then, I found that switching to big-endian gave a yet shorter solution.

Comment: Ah neat, good idea little endian handling.  Hmm, that might be a win for my asm version, removing a level of loop nesting and doing 9 string->byte conversion!  But in C, you may be violating strict aliasing as well, unless you used a union. :)  Fun fact that you probably already know: safe/portable unaligned aliasing-safe loads can be done with `memcpy(&my_unsigned, p, sizeof(unsigned))`, so it is possible to write ungolfed code like that which compiles efficiently when unaligned loads are available.

Comment: Maybe you missed the late edit in a prev comment: I'd suggest using a 2nd `#header` line for the portable C version, to really present it as a separate solution in the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é.○▄╗jF⌐§╥§I╓☻lw«ç┴║╫┼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=822e09dcbb6a46a915d21549d6026c77ae87c1bad7c5&i=127.0.0.1+127.0.0.0%2F24%0A127.0.0.55+127.0.0.0%2F23%0A10.4.1.33+10.4.0.0%2F16%0A255.255.255.255+0.0.0.0%2F0%0A127.1.2.3+127.0.0.0%2F24%0A127.1.2.3+127.1.2.1%2F32%0A10.10.83.255+10.10.84.0%2F22&a=1&m=2)

It takes the input parameters space-separated on standard input.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
'/:/~       split on slash and push the last group back to the input stack
j{          split on space; for each group, run this code block
  './       split on period
  {emVB|E   evaluate integers and decode integer as base-256
  ;e|<      peek from input stack and shift left
  Vu/       integer divide by 2^32
F           end of for-each
=           two values left on stack are equal?
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%27%2F%3A%2F%7E++++%09split+on+slash+and+push+the+last+group+back+to+the+input+stack%0Aj%7B+++++++%09split+on+space%3B+for+each+group,+run+this+code+block%0A++%27.%2F++++%09split+on+period%0A++%7BemVB%7CE%09evaluate+integers+and+decode+integer+as+base-256%0A++%3Be%7C%3C+++%09peek+from+input+stack+and+shift+left%0A++Vu%2F++++%09integer+divide+by+2%5E32%0AF++++++++%09end+of+for-each%0A%3D++++++++%09two+values+left+on+stack+are+equal%3F&i=127.0.0.1+127.0.0.0%2F24%0A127.0.0.55+127.0.0.0%2F23%0A10.4.1.33+10.4.0.0%2F16%0A255.255.255.255+0.0.0.0%2F0%0A127.1.2.3+127.0.0.0%2F24%0A127.1.2.3+127.1.2.1%2F32%0A10.10.83.255+10.10.84.0%2F22&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 machine code function, <s>53</s> 48 bytes

changelog:

- -2 `jz` over the shift instead of using a 64-bit shift to handle the `>>(32-0)` special case.
- -3 return in ZF instead of AL, saving 3 bytes for a `setnz al`.

(See also [Daniel Schepler's 32-bit machine code answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code/185139#185139) based on this, which then evolved to use some other ideas we had.  I'm including my latest version of that at the bottom of this answer.)

---

Returns ZF=0 for host *not* in subnet, ZF=1 for in subnet, so you can branch on the result with `je host_matches_subnet`

Callable with the x86-64 System V calling convention as
`bool not_in_subnet(int dummy_rdi, const char *input_rsi);` if you add in `setnz al`.

The input string contains both the host and network, separated by exactly 1 non-digit character.  The memory following the end of the CIDR width must contain at least 3 non-digit bytes before the end of a page.  (Shouldn't be a problem in most cases, like for a cmdline arg.)  Daniel's 32-bit version doesn't have this limitation.

We run the same dotted-quad parse loop 3 times, getting the two IPv4 addresses, and getting the `/mask` as an integer in the high byte of a dword.  (This is why there has to be readable memory after the `/mask`, but it doesn't matter if there are ASCII digits.)

**We do `(host ^ subnet) >> (32-mask)` to shift out the host bits** (the ones allowed to mismatch), leaving only the difference between the subnet and the host.  To solve the `/0` special case where we need to shift by 32, we jump over the shift on count=0.  (`neg cl` sets ZF, which we can branch on *and* leave as the return value if we don't shift.)  Note that `32-mask mod 32 = -mask`, and x86 scalar shifts mask their count by `& 31` or `& 63`.

```
    line  addr   machine                NASM source.  (from nasm -felf64 -l/dev/stdout)
    num          code bytes

     1                             %use smartalign
     2                             
     3                                 ;10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/23         true
     4                                 ;10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/24         false
     5                             
     6                             ;; https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code
     7                             %ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf64
     8                             in_subnet:
     9                             
    10 00000000 6A03                   push 3
    11 00000002 5F                     pop  rdi                    ; edi = 3 dotted-quads to parse, sort of.
    12                             .parseloop:
    13                             
    14                                 ;xor  ebx,ebx             ; doesn't need to be zeroed first; we end up shifting out the original contents
    15                                 ;lea  ecx, [rbx+4]
    16 00000003 6A04                   push   4
    17 00000005 59                     pop    rcx                  ; rcx = 4 integers in a dotted-quad
    18                             .quadloop:
    19                             
    20 00000006 31D2                   xor   edx,edx               ; standard edx=atoi(rdi) loop terminated by a non-digit char
    21 00000008 EB05                   jmp  .digit_entry
    22                              .digitloop:
    23 0000000A 6BD20A                 imul   edx, 10
    24 0000000D 00C2                   add    dl, al
    25                              .digit_entry:
    26 0000000F AC                     lodsb
    27 00000010 2C30                   sub    al, '0'
    28 00000012 3C09                   cmp    al, 9
    29 00000014 76F4                   jbe   .digitloop
    30                                 ; al=non-digit character - '0'
    31                                 ; RDI pointing to the next character.
    32                                 ; EDX = integer
    33                             
    34 00000016 C1E308                 shl    ebx, 8
    35 00000019 88D3                   mov    bl, dl               ; build a quad 1 byte at a time, ending with the lowest byte
    36 0000001B E2E9                   loop .quadloop
    37                             
    38 0000001D 53                     push   rbx          ; push result to be collected after parsing 3 times
    39 0000001E FFCF                   dec    edi
    40 00000020 75E1                   jnz   .parseloop
    41                             
    42 00000022 59                     pop    rcx   ; /mask  (at the top of a dword)
    43 00000023 5A                     pop    rdx   ; subnet
    44 00000024 58                     pop    rax   ; host
    45 00000025 0FC9                   bswap  ecx   ; cl=network bits  (reusing the quad parse loop left it in the high byte)

    49 00000027 F6D9                   neg    cl
    50 00000029 7404                   jz   .all_net     ; skip the count=32 special case
    51                             
    52 0000002B 31D0                   xor    eax, edx   ; host ^ subnet
    53 0000002D D3E8                   shr    eax, cl    ; shift out the host bits, keeping only the diff of subnet bits
    54                             
    55                             .all_net:
    56                                ; setnz  al         ; return ZF=1 match,  ZF=0 not in subnet
    57 0000002F C3                     ret
    58 00000030 30                 .size:      db $ - in_subnet

              0x30 = 48 bytes
```

(not updated with latest version)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVNb@M2EL3rV8yhW9uNJX9ukMYwetktkFux3UPRxTagxLHEmiIVkkrk/Hl3SMq2vEkNJJKH88H35s2YWYt1Lg@pYrY@Hj@0FsHWzDgmRamSBOizWcyzdbbIVisIb/NsPluu4PRxpsX/91uf/XZMWkySzQYq5xp7P5sVmmOp5S6zjhV77IqKqRKzQtezpxatE1rZ2eLu43z@cSbqVKj0oFuT2jZX6GzqQ4Uqo9HnSoR6jIf38eZNaytYxVfdABgu4J3PBpAOtrACrp1Dnj61jFtwGhpmLE7BauNA77IkCwapddNX2HTaAGDeTenvh6Rco1UjBwqR@2Q5wisaTV92wli3gRcEVBzaBmwldo6wgG4duApBG1EKxSQUWjlUzsZqEhlVK7opfDN5d7P@foEJsL4AJahF9x5Qb97CGgRlLdFYegE2hJ1k/v8AYQBIBBFC3r3JR51TnBnuHbbMaTEmjifg48GhqQkDZYb8QFWUViknWA6o0SYk/7emy2bB@EgozSHpv8ULeBdRt7K/AMkqmBjn/sHlFJhMruJjjNTc5uGN5BAiyHU0HwVTUTcn06/xEtQYGNSNVJPD9vrGrCBEkJ4TbeDLpwfim7j0raMO@84p7AbuWe/5@dNfxHvPeiTWVh5X0A7cBUutn/0jp5tx@ZZqrxEqISzR6dAnixVF87zuYRPr5/4lQ22YoTo30Rq0DAZtK12vz0JLiYXvmKS@xR5xLMI9uYhsqVfP1nkQkreq28CsZnYPMGZRzY5O9c4L7UUbPrmK4DEizu3VCYsnlbbRntsX1gT5B3tB/UFHCfeQC2epmsHWhk5QSc9CjzDQIpHIo0aS3v1xJcoq0DihjXSROSWdQrpaRpYePNtq7wMMjiytgZqwGFHsQYo9xl7sKHC1TBX45yJVU8hphmt2IDq1kgcQOxr0kUHwnPRC@Xm1@A3ga4WK9FL6UKUdeCzZULb@NqtlsHi3YBlOJSAj8SC/EAX/DJm0lemZnFJkBFXoVrktQbQNFsJvGEYcibCpTiaPicHtOiVio@56yaLz3WdyIKXTpiYhPbWC1ATYkfQJ@BK4oCNVOHhmktymAaVfBKamHHOYhZ3gl2JIb@jamRWveB@T8xx@onk7b/XkWEqdU@QjrR3jkviII/@BI/0YIPzx9cufD39/pomKkxdmyljhN6ZtbtZwc3L5ZfE9rH7rVz8z5fO3aPDgu571H6Lv3kSb62iy/E7hBstWMkpzd5vermHsYVPKKPyCSTnAdKlDEzb1HR1YfOOWq0Uk/2BD6Pu/YHT6iB2twdLothlfCoz7y01gkhyP7/5E/wc)

including a `_start` that calls it on `argv[1]` and returns an exit status.

```
## on my desktop
$ ./ipv4-subnet "10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/24"    && echo "$? : in subnet" || echo "$? : not in subnet"
not in subnet

$ ./ipv4-subnet "10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/23"    && echo "$? : in subnet" || echo "$? : not in subnet"
in subnet
```

It works fine if you pass a command line arg containing a newline instead of a space.  But it has to be *instead*, not as well.

---

## x86 32-bit machine code function, 38 bytes

Do 9 integer -> uint8_t parses and "push" them on the stack, where we pop them off as dwords or use the last one still in CL.  Avoids reading past the end of the string at all.

Also, `dec` is only 1 byte in 32-bit mode.

```
    72                             in_subnet:
    73 00000000 89E7                   mov   edi, esp
    74 00000002 51                     push  ecx
    75 00000003 51                     push  ecx                   ; sub esp,8
    76                             .byteloop:
    77                             
    78 00000004 31C9                   xor   ecx,ecx               ; standard ecx=atoi(rdi) loop terminated by a non-digit char
    79                                                             ; runs 9 times: 8 in two dotted-quads, 1 mask length
    80 00000006 EB05                   jmp  .digit_entry
    81                              .digitloop:
    82 00000008 6BC90A                 imul   ecx, 10
    83 0000000B 00C1                   add    cl, al
    84                              .digit_entry:
    85 0000000D AC                     lodsb
    86 0000000E 2C30                   sub    al, '0'
    87 00000010 3C09                   cmp    al, 9
    88 00000012 76F4                   jbe   .digitloop
    89                                 ; RDI pointing to the next character.
    90                                 ; EDX = integer
    91                             
    92 00000014 4F                     dec    edi
    93 00000015 880F                   mov    [edi], cl           ; /mask store goes below ESP but we don't reload it
    94 00000017 39E7                   cmp    edi, esp
    95 00000019 73E9                   jae   .byteloop
    96                             
    97                                 ;; CL = /mask still there from the last conversion
    98                                 ;; ESP pointing at subnet and host on the stack, EDI = ESP-1
    99                             
   100 0000001B 5A                     pop    edx   ; subnet
   101 0000001C 58                     pop    eax   ; host
   102                             
   103 0000001D 31D0                   xor    eax, edx             ; host ^ subnet
   104 0000001F F6D9                   neg    cl                   ; -mask = (32-mask) mod 32;  x86 shifts mask their count
   105 00000021 7402                   jz     .end                 ; 32-n = 32 special case
   106 00000023 D3E8                   shr    eax, cl
   107                             .end:
   108                                 ; setz  al                  ; just return in ZF
   109 00000025 C3                     ret

   110 00000026 26                 .size:      db $ - in_subnet
      0x26 = 38 bytes
```

Test caller

```
   113                             global _start
   114                             _start:
   115 00000027 8B742408               mov    esi, [esp+8]   ; argv[1]
   116 0000002B E8D0FFFFFF             call   in_subnet
   117 00000030 0F95C3                 setnz  bl
   118 00000033 B801000000             mov    eax, 1         ; _exit syscall
   119 00000038 CD80                   int    0x80
```

Comment: I'm curious how the 32-bit asm byte count would go if instead of the `cmp/jcc` that you mentioned you did something like `xor edx,edx;neg cl;cmovz eax,edx;shr eax,cl` - or maybe you already have a 0 value hanging around somewhere.  (And then you wouldn't need the `sub cl,32` instruction.)

Comment: Yup, looks like `edi` should be 0 when the loop exits, so `xor eax,edx;neg cl;cmovz eax,edi;shr eax,cl` should work.

Comment: If I counted things right, `cmove eax,edi` has 3 bytes which is a wash over the removed `sub cl,32` then `shr cl,eax` saves one byte over `shr cl,rax` and 32-bit `dec edi` saves one byte over 64-bit `dec edi`.  My assembly then gives `.byte 0x33` (in GNU binutils syntax) = 51 for `in_subnet.size`.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks.  (In Intel syntax it's `shr eax,cl`, vs. `shr %cl, %eax` in AT&T syntax, your last comment reversed that.)  It's a bit of a chore to update machine-code answers (and port the `_start` caller and re-describe the calling convention for 32-bit mode...), so I might not get around to it.  Feeling lazy today. >.<

Comment: Oh right, forgot about the different calling convention.  If we wanted to keep it SysV ABI compliant then the additional `mov esi,[esp+4]` would wipe out the savings and then some.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: oh, I didn't mean in the code, I meant in the text of the answer.  Being callable from C is merely a bonus, this is an asm / machine-code answer.  I have no problem with a 32-bit function that happens to clobber all the registers except ESP, and takes an arg in ESI.  See my answer on [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020).  It would need a wrapper to be testable from C, but my `_start` caller would be easy to port.

Comment: I just tried implementing the comment you put on my answer about getting rid of the double loop and instead storing into stack variables - and even with the extra code to initialize the write pointer in `edi`, write the output, etc. it ended up saving 2 bytes in net.  (At least once I realized `push ecx;push ecx;push ecx` was shorter than `sub esp,12`; and it seemed to be a wash whether I predecremented `edi` and used `std;stosb;cld` or whether I just stored using `dec edi;mov [edi],al`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: x86-64 SysV has a red-zone below RSP.  Maybe you can justify a 32-bit calling convention with a red-zone to avoid reserving.  But I guess you want to reload it with pop anyway.  `sub esp,12` is a 3-byte instruction, same as 3x push, but maybe your saving came elsewhere?  Anyway, sounds like you could post that as a separate answer; I'd like to see it since you've already put in the work to sort out the details.

Comment: Hmm, I must have been miscounting or accidentally using 64-bit compilation (where of course the byte-by-byte storing won't work as well with `pop` if at all).  You're right, `sub esp,12` is the same length.  And on top of that, now that I built it again in 32-bit mode I get a total of 47 bytes, making 5 bytes saved in addition to the 1 byte from the `cmovz` revision.  I haven't actually run the new code to test it, though.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: yeah, instead of `pop` in 64-bit mode I was thinking `lodsb` /`xchg eax,ecx` for the count, and `lodsd` / `xchg eax,edx` / `lodsd` (so 5 bytes total, not moving RSP).  32-bit `pop` is not encodeable in 64-bit mode, only 16 (operand-size prefix) or 64-bit (no prefix).  A REX.W=0 prefix doesn't actually reduce the operand-size to 32 for instructions where the default operand-size is 64.  But 32-bit mode to enable dword `pop` is probably even better.

Comment: (And BTW, after a 64-bit pop, your options include `shld rdx, rax, 32`, or for performance to avoid a false dependency, `rorx rdx, rax, 32`, or `mov` / `shr`.  But 64-bit `mov r64,r64` is 3 bytes, while push/pop is only 2, so you might win by `push rax`/`pop rdx`/`shr rdx,32`.  Probably most golfy to just use `lodsd` instead of `pop`)

Comment: Posted my revised version: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code/185139#185139

Comment: @DanielSchepler: updated the 64-bit version, and included the 32-bit version I posted in a comment under your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>75</del> <del>73</del>, 71 bytes

```php
<?=strtok($argv[2],'/')==long2ip(ip2long($argv[1])&1+~1<<32-strtok(_));
```

A fork of [@Luis felipe De jesus Munoz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code#185011)'s answer, as a standalone taking input from command line args.  Outputs `'1'` for Truthy, `''` (empty string) for Fasley.

```php
$ php ipsn.php 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.0/24
1
$ php ipsn.php 127.1.2.3 127.0.0.0/24
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSoJD9bQyWxKL0s2ihWR11fXdPWNic/L90os0Ajs8AIxIRKG8Zqqhlq1xna2Bgb6UI1xmtqWv///9/QyFzPAAgN4SwDfSMTAA)

-2 bytes borrowing [@Christoph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code#185011)'s little trick for `strtok()`. His answer is still shorter though!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
ṣ”/ṣ€”.Vḅ⁹s2+Ø%BḊ€ḣ€ʋ/E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGubqg6imNUCWXtjDHa2PGncWG2kfnqHq9HBHF1D84Q6Q7Klufdf/Oo8a5ijo2ikAleocbj866eHOGSpcD3dvOdwOVBH5/7@hkbmegZ6hnqmxPoQJhPpGxlwwjqkpmriBnglQuTFQOYgFEjU04zIyNdVDwvoGUA0GYHMM9Yz0UIw3QRMGsQz1jY1ApgORhTHYECjHBKTDCAA)

Monadic link that takes a the address and subnet separated by a slash and returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

Thanks to @gwaugh for pointing out a flaw in the original - it failed to ensure the binary list was 32 long.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
≔⪪Ｓ/θ≔Ｉ⊟θζ⊞θＳＵＭθ÷↨Ｉ⪪ι.²⁵⁶Ｘ²⁻³²ζ⁼⊟θ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NCoMwEITvPoV42oCNf60XT63toQdB8AmCigY0Jiax0JdPE/XSy7LszH4z7UjWdiGTMXcp6cCg4RNV8GZcq0atlA2AQj@IAjsFKrzTVRKpoF44CGSFrxVqLUcQof/3ae8V4eUyz4R1h6qedKNdDw8i@wNzJFKbggNHS2@5nfXy6VdIQ7@iTEvIUheDHLG2bAUvockkzw7OvndBhTFJjK84xnGU5N6@JzjLzGWbfg) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the subnet as the first parameter and and outputs `-` only if the address lies within the subnet. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ｓ/θ
```

Split the subnet on `/`.

```
≔Ｉ⊟θζ
```

Remove the mask and cast it to integer.

```
⊞θＳ
```

Push the address to the array.

```
ＵＭθ÷↨Ｉ⪪ι.²⁵⁶Ｘ²⁻³²ζ
```

Split both addresses on `.`, convert them to integers, interpret as base 256, and discard the masked bits.

```
⁼⊟θ⊟θ
```

Compare the two values.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint -MSocket=:all -p`, 72 bytes

```perl
sub c{unpack N,inet_aton pop}<>=~/(.*)\/(.*)/;$_=c($_)-&c($1)<2**(32-$2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZNC8IgAIDhe7/CwwiV/Jhr0MfsH9SlayBOJGSi0twp6qdnUpf3eZN9@L6UeRmBeS4haTOBy8YFm5XOMYAU02s4yTeDFKPbr@zYKGlgoxBZV1o0CIxhJ0gjUCmcctrR/ervjontJ6bsYpgLOfeUt7w6ursLuc41mslmedDeF5K@)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'/¡`U‚ε'.¡b8jð0:JX£}Ë
```

Takes the subnet before the address.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXf/QwoTQRw2zzm1V1zu0MMki6/AGAyuviEOLaw93//9vaGSuZwCC@kYmXDCOIQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/h5ulir6SQmJeioGQPZj5qmwRkFv9X1z@0MCH0UcOsc1vV9Q4tTLLIOrzBwMor4tDi2sPd/3X@GxqZ6xmAoL6RCReMY8iFJGwM55iaYhM3BIsb6JmAhQ3NIGxDPWNjLgOoWgMuI1NTPSTMhWGtoZ6RnjGcZahvbIQsDLTFQM/CBKTcCMYzBhkEAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'/¡              '# Split the first subnet-input by "/"
   `              # Push both values separated to the stack
    U             # Pop and store the trailing number in variable `X`
    ‚             # Pair the subnet-IP with the second address-input
     ε            # Map both to:
      '.¡        '#  Split on "."
         b        #  Convert each integer to binary
          8j      #  Add leading spaces to make them size 8
          ð0:     #  And replace those spaces with "0"
             J    #  Join the four parts together to a single string
              X£  #  And only leave the first `X` binary digits as substring
     }Ë           # After the map: check if both mapped values are the same
                  # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## R     120 bytes

a function - I pasted ".32" to first term

`w=function(a,b){f=function(x)as.double(el(strsplit(x,"[./]")));t=f(paste0(a,".32"))-f(b);sum(t[-5]*c(256^(3:0)))<2^t[5]}`

and just for fun:

`require("iptools");w=function(a,b)ips_in_cidrs(a,b)[[2]]`

which is 56 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Java <s>215 211 207 202 200 199 198 190</s> 180 bytes

```java
Long k,c;boolean a(String i,String s){return(b(i)^b(s))>>32-k.decode(s.split("/")[1])==0;}long b(String i){for(c=k=0l;c<4;k+=k.decode(i.split("[./]")[3+(int)-c])<<8*c++);return k;}
```

Outputs `true` for truthy and `false` for falsy.

Note: This uses `long` instead of `int` for the potential right shift of 32.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdBNT8MgGAfw@z4F6QnsRumbLum6oyc96W2ZCaWorAyaQmdM089eqdZFL@oWQwgPhPx4/uzogS50zdWurAYmqTHglgrVDTdaPYFqzrJCa8mpAhTe2Ua4QzGfCoO6htu2UbCAAj0U0CC0XsfRosIlZ7rk0GBTS2GhF3hoE25RnpOsl6NcHDXUPeoGsrzKiczYKskqPz8C4hPY4GDrjNiHQlm0YFu0Wi0vmO@j7KMHUGX9ULeFFAwYS61bDlqUYO/STG9ttgUC3WzMByjIgeIv72EhymZ3r8byPdatxbW7a6WCFFPohdEVJm6E3vxYkyBKPAR84AHzrFtZgoKD@6bl3h@gNP0uxWdK4X9IBCcOiuMRGuvRCS9PdqI0xV@m08jUFDkrXYgjHP/24ddUmpOksQ6DODpDct9N8DKewk3bZOzrB62f9cMb)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Saved 10 bytes thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206/peter-cordes)

Comment: This doesn't output a "distinct and consistent value" for falsey.

Comment: I'd argue that it's distinctly and consistently non-zero but if that's not the spirit of the challenge, I can change it.

Comment: A 64-bit integer supports left-shifts by 32.  Also, you can *right* shift `host ^ net` to shift out the bits you want to remove, instead of actually creating a mask.  But I guess Java needs a compare in there to create a boolean from an integer.  Maybe a `!`, because it doesn't matter which of true or false you produce for which output.  (I asked the OP for clarification about whether they intended to exclude 0 / non-zero, and [they said](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im#comment443751_185005) yes they were aware of the consequences of that wording:

Comment: @PeterCordes Converting everything to `long` does lose me some bytes but I make up for it by being able to remove the ternary and doing the XOR as you suggest. I'm checking what else I can golf before posting

Answer (score 1):

## x86 assembly function, <del>49</del> 43 bytes

This is mostly posted to satisfy Peter Cordes's request for the revised version I created.  It can probably go away once/if he incorporates it into his answer.

This function expects `esi` to point to an input string, with the address and subnet parts separated either by a space or a newline character, and the return value is in the ZF flag (which by definition has only two possible values).

```
 1                                  %use smartalign
 2                                  
 3                                      ;10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/23         true
 4                                      ;10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/24         false
 5                                  
 6                                  ;; https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185005/im-in-your-subnets-golfing-your-code
 7                                  in_subnet:
 8                                  
 9                                      ;xor  ebx,ebx             ; doesn't need to be zeroed first; we end up shifting out the original contents
10                                      ;lea  ecx, [rbx+4]
11 00000000 6A09                        push   9
12 00000002 59                          pop    ecx                  ; ecx = 9 integers (8 in two dotted-quads,
13                                                                  ; 1 mask length)
14                                  
15 00000003 89E7                        mov   edi, esp
16 00000005 83EC0C                      sub   esp, 12
17                                  .quadloop:
18                                  
19 00000008 31D2                        xor   edx,edx               ; standard edx=atoi(rdi) loop terminated by a non-digit char
20 0000000A EB05                        jmp  .digit_entry
21                                   .digitloop:
22 0000000C 6BD20A                      imul   edx, 10
23 0000000F 00C2                        add    dl, al
24                                   .digit_entry:
25 00000011 AC                          lodsb
26 00000012 2C30                        sub    al, '0'
27 00000014 3C09                        cmp    al, 9
28 00000016 76F4                        jbe   .digitloop
29                                      ; al=non-digit character - '0'
30                                      ; RDI pointing to the next character.
31                                      ; EDX = integer
32                                  
33 00000018 4F                          dec    edi
34 00000019 8817                        mov    [edi], dl
35 0000001B E2EB                        loop .quadloop
36                                  
37 0000001D 59                          pop    ecx   ; /mask  (at the top of a dword)
38 0000001E 5A                          pop    edx   ; subnet
39 0000001F 58                          pop    eax   ; host
40 00000020 0FC9                        bswap  ecx   ; cl=network bits  (reusing the quad parse loop left it in the high byte)
41                                  
42                                  ;    xor    cl, -32    ; I think there's some trick like this for 32-n or 31-n, but maybe only if we're masking to &31?  Then neg or not work.
43                                  
44 00000022 31D0                        xor    eax, edx   ; host ^ subnet
45                                  ;    xor    edx, edx   ; edx = 0
46 00000024 F6D9                        neg    cl
47 00000026 7402                        jz     .end
48 00000028 D3E8                        shr    eax, cl    ; count=32 special case isn't special for a 64-bit shift
49                                  .end:    
50 0000002A C3                          ret
51 0000002B 2B                      .size:      db $ - in_subnet
```

And the x86 Linux wrapper part:

```
53                                  global _start
54                                  _start:
55 0000002C 8B742408                    mov    esi, [esp+8]   ; argv[1]
56 00000030 E8CBFFFFFF                  call   in_subnet
57 00000035 0F95C0                      setnz  al
58 00000038 0FB6D8                      movzx  ebx, al
59 0000003B B801000000                  mov    eax, 1         ; _exit syscall
60 00000040 CD80                        int    0x80
```

-6 bytes due to suggestion from Peter Cordes to return the value in ZF.

Comment: I guess I could save one byte by removing the last `xor edx,edx` and replacing `cmovz eax,edx` with `jz .nonzero; xor eax,eax; .nonzero:`.  `cmovz` still wins if we have calling convention `ebx=0`.

Comment: Can we just `jz` over the `shr` to the setz or the ret?  We can swap the `setnz` to `setz` and return `1` for a match if that helps.  Or even say that our return value *is* ZF.  I should have done that in my answer.  (But I don't think we can justify requiring the caller to create constants for us, like `ebx=0`.  My answer on [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) argues that would be stretching a custom calling convention too far.

Comment: BTW, I use `cut` to remove some columns from the NASM listing output because all my instructions are short:  `nasm -felf foo.asm -l/dev/stdout | cut -b -34,$((34+6))-`.  Also, I used mov instead of movzx in my `_start` caller because the exit status comes from the low byte of the arg to `sys_exit()`.  The kernel ignores the higher bytes.

Comment: I guess that would work.  That takes the count down to 43 bytes and then I insert `setnz al` after `call in_subnet` in the wrapper.

Comment: Yup.  Easy to imagine the normal use case for this function would be `call`/`je`, rather than printing or further passing along the result.  Like I pointed out in the "tips", some system-call calling conventions already do this in real life (usually with CF=error).

Comment: I reworked your loop to use `cmp edi, esp` / `jae` instead of `loop`, leaving the last conversion in CL so we don't need to pop / bswap it, or even `mov cl,dl`.  And we drop the `push 9 / pop ecx`, and reduce `sub esp,12` to 2x `push ecx`.  https://godbolt.org/z/j-brRj  38 bytes.  And I cleaned up the comments to fit this version.  Tested for `10.4.1.33 10.4.0.0/23` vs. `/24`.  I think I'll keep my answer with the 64-bit version, and this answer has evolved into its own strategy that's arguably different enough to stand alone, as well as being for a different x86 mode.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 26 bytes

```
Ëq'/
ËÎq. Ë°¤ù8Ã¬¯Ug1,1Ãr¶
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVJt&code=y3EnLwrLznEuIMuwpPk4w6yvVWcxLDHDcrY&input=WwpbIjEyNy4wLjAuMSIsIjEyNy4wLjAuMC8yNCJdLApbIjEyNy4wLjAuNTUiLCIxMjcuMC4wLjAvMjMiXSwKWyIxMjcuMC4xLjU1IiwiMTI3LjAuMC4wLzIzIl0sClsiMTAuNC4xLjMzIiwiMTAuNC4wLjAvMTYiXSwKWyIyNTUuMjU1LjI1NS4yNTUiLCIwLjAuMC4wLzAiXSwKWyIxMjcuMS4yLjMiLCIxMjcuMC4wLjAvMjQiXSwKWyIxMjcuMS4yLjMiLCIxMjcuMS4yLjEvMzIiXSwKWyIxMC4xMC44My4yNTUiLCIxMC4xMC44NC4wLzIyIl0KXQ)

-3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy!

Input is an array with 2 elements `[address, subnet]`. Transpiled JS below:

```
// U: implicit input array
// split elements in U on the / and
// save back to U using a map function
U = U.m(function(D, E, F) {
  return D.q("/")
});
// map the result of the previous operation
// through another function
U.m(function(D, E, F) {
  return D
    // get the address portion of the / split
    // value and split again on .
    .g().q(".")
    // map each octet through another function
    .m(function(D, E, F) {
      // convert the octet to a base 2 string
      // left padded to a length of 8
      return (D++).s(2).ù(8)
    })
    // join the base 2 octets
    .q()
    // take the left bits of the joined octets
    // determined by subnet size
    .s(0, U.g(1, 1))
})
  // at this point, the intermediate result
  // contains 2 masked values, reduce
  // using === to check for equality
  .r("===")
```

Comment: [26 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVJt&code=y3EnLwrLznEuIMuwpPk4w6yvVWcxLDHDcrY&input=WwpbIjEyNy4wLjAuMSIsIjEyNy4wLjAuMC8yNCJdLApbIjEyNy4wLjAuNTUiLCIxMjcuMC4wLjAvMjMiXSwKWyIxMjcuMC4xLjU1IiwiMTI3LjAuMC4wLzIzIl0sClsiMTAuNC4xLjMzIiwiMTAuNC4wLjAvMTYiXSwKWyIyNTUuMjU1LjI1NS4yNTUiLCIwLjAuMC4wLzAiXSwKWyIxMjcuMS4yLjMiLCIxMjcuMC4wLjAvMjQiXSwKWyIxMjcuMS4yLjMiLCIxMjcuMS4yLjEvMzIiXSwKWyIxMC4xMC44My4yNTUiLCIxMC4xMC44NC4wLzIyIl0KXQ)

Comment: Interesting - I didn't realize you could coerce a string to a number with `++`.

Comment: Yup, just like you can in JS. It's no use, though, if you need to resuse the original value later on, though, but it is handy on occasion.

Comment: The need for the comma in the `g` method is annoying me; can't figure out a way around it at all. At least not one that'll save you a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 187 bytes

```cs
a=>{var b=a.Select(x=>x.Split(".").SelectMany(g=>Convert.ToString(int.Parse(g.Split("/")[0]),2).PadLeft(8)).Take(int.Parse(a[1].Split("/")[1])));return b.First().SequenceEqual(b.Last());}
```

I can definitely golf this down more.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9Ba4MwHMXv@RSdpwRimsS6FZxexgqDDspa2EE8RJd2oRLXGNsO8bN36uwmlCTw3i95/0ey0s1KdVlUOnssrVF6Fyc4LYo82oYXEUb1UZhJGgqylrnMLDyH0Zmsv3JloUMcNOBXob/hLoyeCn2UxpJNse5nQaUtWQlTSri7pqYOimmCMEftzcdSbi2cI0Q2Yi9Hz0XMknGCJQihwEhbGT1JyUKZ0sKu/lBJncnnQyVymJKl6DAKmksATp8ql/BFk5WUe4juQpchUIPfX05E@CbbeqUlRDgdmQC8G2Vlb5yaYpfTpmbYZX5T88bBAqd4C7U8xUnd6qZtA82F8QdC28XAVdEpn/0Z3x9zbzDsllMya7E3qI6ye8B9n4wOoEOA9mFGOPFua/9xp9jU493Mds@9fshgZl2C/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## **Ruby (48 bytes)**

```
require 'ipaddr'
lambda{|a,m|IPAddr.new(m)===a}
```

Comment: [You can remove the whitespace around `====`](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFVBPbMgMSWlSJ0rzTYnMTcpJbG6JlEnt8YzwBEoqpeXWq6Rq2lra5tYy1VQWlKskKaXnJiTo6FkaGSuZwCEhko6cLaBvpGJkub//wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 134 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Select(x=>x.Split('.','/').Take(4).Aggregate(0L,(y,z)=>y<<8|int.Parse(z))>>32-int.Parse(a[1].Split('/')[1])).Distinct().Count()<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5fS8MwFMXf8yl0L00gvUvSVgdrC6IIwh7ECT6MPWQ1q2ElkzZjf2o/e01n5wYjCff8Dpxzk1V@Vun2eWOyuLKlNvlsThfrdZEuk1YmqYSpKlRm8S5JdzD9LrTFHnjUG3oE3uVK4ZDAQ56XKpdWYTaheE8PJEn3cTz60cbCqywrhQ@EpGkg/LMjZ3x@KnRljgiBJ11Zbdw6Ao/rjXEzFu0Ybb90ofCLgVelVpjcJj4nqEZ/H76RyZuSnxNtFCZ0cQFj9FFqq44wqBn1BWtqTn0eNbVoBlTSBV1io7azee10Q1yiabm4B@YORyfFhiL8hyi69IMe@LXPIHR20KvO5XdIRBFcPMT6ADuGOQgIrtee7U7xYSC6TndHwbGkh7BLiF8)

LINQ statement that takes a 2-element string array as input in `[address, subnet]` format.

Each dotted quad is converted into 32 bits of a long using bit manipulation. The bits are right shifted by the subnet size and elements are compared for equality.

There were a couple of C# answers at the time that this answer was posted, but none that used pure bit manipulation.

```cs
// a: input array containing address and subnet
a=>a
  // iterate over input elements
  .Select(x=>x
    // split element on . and /
    .Split('.','/')
    // the subnet will have 5 elements,
    // we only want the parts before the /
    .Take(4)
    // use an aggregate function to convert dotted quad to 32 bits
    .Aggregate(0L,(y,z)=>y<<8|int.Parse(z))
    // shift bits of aggregate to the right
    >>
    // shift amount determined by subnet size
    32-int.Parse(a[1].Split('/')[1])
  )
  // test for equality by checking if number
  // of unique values is equal to 1
  .Distinct()
  .Count()<2
```