# Parse a Unicode vulgar fraction

Tags: code-golf, parsing, rational-numbers, unicode

## Objective

Given a string with single Unicode vulgar fraction, parse it to a rational number.

## Valid inputs

A valid input is one of:

- `¼` U+00BC; one quarter
- `½` U+00BD; one half
- `¾` U+00BE; three quarters
- `⅐` U+2150; one seventh
- `⅑` U+2151; one ninth
- `⅒` U+2152; one tenth
- `⅓` U+2153; one third
- `⅔` U+2154; two thirds
- `⅕` U+2155; one fifth
- `⅖` U+2156; two fifths
- `⅗` U+2157; three fifths
- `⅘` U+2158; four fifths
- `⅙` U+2159; one sixth
- `⅚` U+215A; five sixths
- `⅛` U+215B; one eighth
- `⅜` U+215C; three eighths
- `⅝` U+215D; five eighths
- `⅞` U+215E; seven eighths
- `⅟` (U+215F; fraction numerator one) followed by ASCII decimal digits (U+0030 – U+0039)
- ASCII decimal digits followed by `⁄`(U+2044; fraction slash) followed by ASCII decimal digits

There are exceptions. See below.

## Invalid inputs

If the denominator is zero, the parser must fall in an erroneous state. This includes:

- Monadic failing
- Returning an erroneous value
- Throwing an error

## Rules

1. Encoding of the input doesn't matter.
2. Output type and format doesn't matter either. Though native rational number type is preferred, a pair of integers is permitted.
3. Inputs that are neither valid nor invalid fall in *don't care* situation. This includes:

   - Whole numbers
   - Improper fractions
   - Reducible fractions
   - Fractions with zero numerator
   - Negative fractions

## Examples

`⅛` (U+215B) parses to one eighth.

`⅟13` (U+215F U+0031 U+0033) parses to one thirteenth.

`24⁄247` (U+0032 U+0034 U+2044 U+0032 U+0034 U+0037) parses to twenty-four 247ths.

`1⁄7` (U+0031 U+2044 U+0037) parses to one seventh. Note that `⅐` and `⅟7` will parse to the same.

`0` (U+0030) falls in *don't care* situation. It's a whole number.

`9⁄8` (U+0039 U+2044 U+0038) falls in *don't care* situation. It's an improper fraction.

`4⁄8` (U+0034 U+2044 U+0038) falls in *don't care* situation. It's reducible to one half.

`↉` (U+2189) falls in *don't care* situation. Its numerator is zero.

`-½` (U+002D U+00BD) falls in *don't care* situation. It is negative.

`1⁄0` (U+0031 U+2044 U+0030) must make the parser be in erroneous state. Its denominator is zero.

## Ungolfed solution

### Haskell

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Ratio
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP as ReadP
import Text.Read
import Text.Read.Lex

fractionParser :: ReadP Rational
fractionParser = choice [
    char '¼' >> return (1 % 4),
    char '½' >> return (1 % 2),
    char '¾' >> return (3 % 4),
    char '⅐' >> return (1 % 7),
    char '⅑' >> return (1 % 9),
    char '⅒' >> return (1 % 10),
    char '⅓' >> return (1 % 3),
    char '⅔' >> return (2 % 3),
    char '⅕' >> return (1 % 5),
    char '⅖' >> return (2 % 5),
    char '⅗' >> return (3 % 5),
    char '⅘' >> return (4 % 5),
    char '⅙' >> return (1 % 6),
    char '⅚' >> return (5 % 6),
    char '⅛' >> return (1 % 8),
    char '⅜' >> return (3 % 8),
    char '⅝' >> return (5 % 8),
    char '⅞' >> return (7 % 8),
    char '⅟' >> do
        d <- readDecP
        guard (0 /= d)
        return (1 % d),
    do
        n <- readDecP
        char '⁄'
        d <- readDecP
        guard (0 /= d)
        return (n % d)
    ]
```

Comment: @l4m2 The percent symbol is not considered a fraction. So it falls in *don't care* situation.

Comment: In case it gladdens anyone's heart, I'll point out that Mathematica has a builtin, `ToExpression`, that converts a string to a number or other mathematical expression ... that utterly fails to understand these symbols  :)

Comment: @GregMartin *Finally! Years after the [upgoat incident](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/20929), Mathematica's builtins' invulnerability takes a hit!*

Comment: Related fun fact: the character ༳ (U+0F33) has a Numeric_Value property of -1/2.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk Seriously? Zero denominators are the only incorrect input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 17 bytes

```perl6
{S!\⅟!1/!.EVAL}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Olgx5lHrfEVDfUU91zBHn9r/aflFCtFKh/Yo6Sgd2gsi9gGJR60TwOREMDkJTE4Gk1PA5FQwOQ1MTgeTM8DkTDA5C0zOBpNzwORcMDkPTM43NAbSRib6RibmQIahvjlEGMIxUIpVqOZSKE6sVEhTUInnqlX4DwA)

Returns a rational number type. Raku actually natively supports unicode literals and operators, though it doesn't do `⅟`, so we need to substitute for that. Also, division by zero won't cause an error, but returns a value that causes an Exception when you try to use or print it.

Comment: The right tool for the job. :)

Comment: But what about `for ["0/0","¼","½","¾","⅐","⅑","⅒","⅓","⅔","⅕","⅖","⅗","⅘","⅙","⅚","⅛","⅜","⅝","⅞","⅟13","24/247","1/7","1/0","⅟7"] {
 say f $_
} `  ;) The first exception crashes it and it does not look at the other elements! ;)

Comment: @MBaas `0/0` is not a valid input since the numerator is 0. Even if it wasn't, division by zero is *meant* to be an exception

Comment: Sure - but is that a reason not to evaluate the others? (I think "Invalid Inputs" indicated it should be handled)   ;)

Comment: 'According to the Perl 6 FAQ, Perl 6 was designed to mitigate "the usual suspects" that elicit the "line noise" claim from Perl 5 critics'... Yeah, right.

Answer (score 9):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 80 bytes

```php
preg_match("~(\d+)/ ?(\d+)~",iconv('','US//TRANSLIT',$argn),$m);echo$m[1]/$m[2];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkC4pS0@NzE0uSMzSU6jRiUrQ19RXswXSdkk5mcn5emYa6uo56aLC@fkiQo1@wj2eIuo5KYlF6nqaOSq6mdWpyRr5KbrRhrD6QNIq1/g8SUFCKyYvJU7LmSssvSk0EGh2tdGiPko7Sob0gYh@QeNQ6AUxOBJOTwORkMDkFTE4Fk9PA5HQwOQNMzgSTs8DkbDA5B0zOBZPzwOR8Q2MgbWSib2RiDmQY6ptDhCEcA6VYhcRiBYgXqrkUgADiZLCIgq6dAtDdIFFqhwySVeCwqf0P9Pi//IKSzPy84v@6bgA)

Just letting `iconv` do all the work for us ^^ this time PHP is competitive :O

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>125 120</s>  106 bytes

```javascript
s=>([n,d]=s.split(/\D/),d)?(n||1)/d:'131111121234151357'[i=s.charCodeAt()%63%20]/-~'133689224444557777'[i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k4jOk8nJda2WK@4ICezREM/xkVfUydF014jr6bGUFM/xUrd0NgQBIwMjYxNDE0NjU3N1aMzgRqSMxKLnIEGOZZoaKqaGasaGcTq69YBlRubWVgaGZkAgampORAAlcf@T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNNQetQ6W0lTkwtDdL6hMRZxI5NHjS1GJuZYpAyBMrjEDbBaMQko@h8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 62 bytes

```
¿№θ⁄⪫⪪θ⁄¦/¿№θ⅟⭆θ⎇κι1/«§”)⧴≦Y�δ↥1≧Ｙ”℅θ/Ｉ⊕§”)¶@≦ＩＧ@℅⁵∧ψ”℅θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8zTUHDOb80r0SjUEdB6VFji5KmpkJAUSZQwCs/M08juCAnE0kOSOsDVVhzpeYUpyqgaW6dj9AcXAKk0n0TC0BSIalFeYlFlRrZOgqZQIWGICNgZlRzcUJ0OJZ45qWkVmgoGYKBkaGRsYmhqaGxqbmBgYGhko6Cf1FKZl5ijkYhWDNUF8g5cI5zYnGJhmdeclFqbmpeSWoKkpnGZhaWRkYmQGBqag4EQDON0cwEmVr7//@j1kn/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a pair of integers separated with `/` for convenience. Explanation:

```
¿№θ⁄
```

If the input contains `⁄`,

```
⪫⪪θ⁄¦/
```

then replace it with a `/`.

```
¿№θ⅟
```

If the input contains `⅟`,

```
⭆θ⎇κι1/
```

then replace it with `1/`.

```
«§”)⧴≦Y�δ↥1≧Ｙ”℅θ/Ｉ⊕§”)¶@≦ＩＧ@℅⁵∧ψ”℅θ
```

Otherwise look up the ordinal of the input in two compressed strings, one for the numerator, one for the denominator, and then increment the denominator (so that `1/10` can be handled).

Alternative version for 73 bytes:

```
¿№θ⁄«≔Ｉ⪪θ⁄θＩ∕§θ⁰⊟θ»¿№θ⅟«Ｉ∕¹Ｉ✂θ¹»Ｉ∕⊕§”)➙⧴ω⪪B⪪◨ιＹ”℅θ⊕§”)¶@≦ＩＧ@℅⁵∧ψ”℅θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NCsIwFITX9hSPrhKIkLT1j66Kbrqy4AlKGzUQ019FEBeCXsALeDcvEtNaRKyze7z5ZibZxmWSxVJrsQY0z/aqRgUB@3m52hjDyRoEVSU2Cs3jqkarXIrvP4EC@9YgKoXBWsdCHETKUVCHKuXHxkqNK8pyVGAj3zoDlxWHn7bbo2vrRzEC724pEt64Ge6SrDapT4QqKfmOq5qnnyE2bcUoc1zqUccbN6dNYFmmQsWynUfgL8rc8XTmOJ7RaDQxMqT7gzaLtH7e7np4kC8) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is a decimal fraction. Explanation:

```
¿№θ⁄«≔Ｉ⪪θ⁄θＩ∕§θ⁰⊟θ»
```

Handle the `⁄` case by dividing the numerator by the denominator.

```
¿№θ⅟«Ｉ∕¹Ｉ✂θ¹»
```

Handle the `⅟` case by taking the reciprocal of the denominator.

```
Ｉ∕⊕§”)➙⧴ω⪪B⪪◨ιＹ”℅θ⊕§”)¶@≦ＩＧ@℅⁵∧ψ”℅θ
```

Look up the decremented numerator and denominator in two compressed strings and divide their increments. (As I need the numerator as an integer anyway, incrementing it actually makes the string more compressible.)

Answer (score 4):

## Groovy, 96 bytes

```
import static java.text.Normalizer.*
def f={s->Eval.me(normalize(s,Form.NFKC).replace("⁄","/"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/M7cgv6hEobgksSQzWSErsSxRryS1okTPL78oNzEnsyq1SE@LKyU1TSHNtrpY1861LDFHLzdVIw8mrVGs4wZk6/m5eTtr6hWlFuQkJqdqKD1qbFHSUdJX0tSs/Z9YXJwKtCINKNo6W0lTwdZWwVDfggtZeL6hMUzC0Pg/AA)

Uses Unicode Normalization to replace the digits with ASCII digits. Then replaces the fraction slash by an ASCII slash and evaluates the resulting string.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval(normalize('NFKC',s).replace(*'⁄/'))
from unicodedata import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc67CsIwGIbhvVcRujQpxeNWcBJcBG9AHWKbYiBNSloF3QTdPZ8PN6IOXkpvpLb@4PI@3/hFk2SoZD0LGr1M0HDgUxS7bEwFlkqHVPApw1an1W5aTkxKmkWCegzbVjqbly1CjECrEI0k95TPfJpQxMNI6cTOAqURR1x2DfPzNJ28r1/fRdPFElgBa2ADbIEdsAcOwBE4AWfgAlyBG3AHHrXCav73Pyqm0XdRpLlMcIA5IdkX)

A lazy built-in solution in Python.

2 bytes saved by dingledooper.

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc67CsIwGIbhvVcRujQpxeNWcBJcBG9AHWKbYiBNSloF3QTdPZ8PN6IOXkpvpLb@4PI@3/hFk2SoZD0LGr1M0HDgUxS7bEwFlkqHVPApw1an1W5aTkxKmkWCegzbVjqbly1CjECrEI0k95TPfJpQxMNI6cTOAqURR1x2DfPzNJ28r1/fRdPFElgBa2ADbIEdsAcOwBE4AWfgAlyBG3AHHrXCav73Pyqm0XdRpLlMcIA5IdkX)

Comment: Does the result conform to the output requirements? Although they allow any (complex, i. e. not simple) number type, I don’t think that numerical approximations are permitted. See [my candidate](/a/205731/68800) for an explanation of an exact solution.

Comment: This was also my first impression after reading the task, but almost all other answers do the same thing, so I guess everybody is fine with that...

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>90</s> <s>88</s> 65 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gi•QλÖìʒ¨ù·'á!÷€āW•2ô2ÝƵ∞+14ÝŽX=+«çIkè`>/ëćÇŽX€åizë\ŽW&ç¡`D_iõEë/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AXcAiP9vc2FiaWX//2dp4oCiUc67w5bDrMqSwqjDucK3J8OhIcO34oKsxIFX4oCiMsO0MsOdxrXiiJ4rMTTDncW9WD0rwqvDp0lrw6hgPi/Dq8SHw4fFvVjigqzDpWl6w6tcxb1XJsOnwqFgRF9pw7VFw6sv///ihZ8yMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCf/TMx81LAo8t/vwtMNrTk06tOLwzkPb1Q8vVDy8/VHTmiON4UBZo8NbjA7PPbb1Ucc8bUOTw3OP7o2w1T60@vDyyuzDKxLs9A@vPtJ@uB0oCtRxeGlm1eHVMUf3hqsdXn5oYYJLfObhra6HV@v/r62t1fkfrXRoj5KO0qG9IGIfkHjUOgFMTgSTk8DkZDA5BUxOBZPTwOR0MDkDTM4Ek7PA5GwwOQdMzgWT88DkfENjIG1k8qixxcjEHMg0BLLMIVIwroFSLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
gi                       # If the length of the (implicit) input is 1:
  •QλÖìʒ¨ù·'á!÷€āW•     '#  Push compressed integer 131133161819122214243444155517375777
                   2ô    #  Split it into parts of size 2:
                         #   [13,11,33,16,18,19,12,22,14,24,34,44,15,55,17,37,57,77]
  2Ý                     #  Push list [0,1,2]
    Ƶ∞                   #  Push compressed integer 188
      +                  #  Add it to each value
       14Ý               #  Push list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
          ŽX=            #  Push compressed integer 8528
             +           #  Add it to each value
              «          #  Merge the two lists together
               ç         #  Convert each to a character: 
                         #   ["¼","½","¾","⅐","⅑","⅒","⅓","⅔","⅕","⅖","⅗","⅘","⅙","⅚","⅛","⅜","⅝","⅞"
                Ik       #  Get the index of the input in this list
                  è      #  Use it to index into the list we created earlier
                   `     #  Pop and push both digits separated to the stack
                    >    #  Increase the denominator by 1
                     /   #  And divide them by one another
 ë                       # Else (the length is not 1):
  ć                      #  Extract the first character of the (implicit) input
   Ç                     #  Convert it to a unicode integer-list
    ŽX€                  #  Push compressed integer 8543
       åi                #  If it's in the list (thus the first character was '⅟'):
         z               #   Push 1 divided by the remaining value
        ë                #  Else (the first character is not '⅟'):
         \               #   Discard the partial input
          ŽW&            #   Push compressed integer 8260
             ç           #   Convert it to a character "⁄"
              ¡          #   Split the (implicit) input by "⁄"
               `         #   Push both values separated to the stack
                D_i      #   If the top value (the denominator) is 0:
                   õE    #    Loop "" amount of times, resulting in an error
                  ë      #   Else:
                   /     #    Divide the two values by one another
                         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how all the compressed integers work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 136 bytes

```
T`¼-¾⅐-⅟`L
B
1/2
D
1/7
E
1/9
F
1/10
G|H
$&3
A|C
$&4
[I-L]
$&5
M|N
$&6
[O-R]
$&8
[AGIMOS]
1/
H|J
2/
[CKP]
3/
L
4/
N|Q
5/
R
7/
⁄
/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZPPbtNAEMbv8xRzQJSqNf4TByfHUqAtpC0UeooidRNP6hX2brS7bgTKpVKDxI07h74IcMij5EXCOE6lNOIQcdnxruf7zef9ZENOKrFYfLqa/fJmf@bTH958en/VgZcQ@hG84jWB17y24Q2vYQBHk2N48rQBB5NDrjF0T7xOj5@acDo54/oCuufeRXXSgu7B0cnp@cceK@F48hYiH7qH7973oOFDB2IfziYfoOnDBSQ@zG/vwF8s5tOf@OxyLwqb/V0cCWPJotOoFSHJ68xlzwHYYthYdQ3xci8IGmFdGpsal0njiNRSF8U8JIqTSsrNUa2JuURBHOPmIZdknefGzPniDXVpkCkus8wMGfkADB@Rkk0vlm4qI/uotKucCYd84ShUyvU@wbHM81qynJaxQhTEM4IVP9jFochzi1JhqtWOw4Ew3CVdKZzUah@l27EocJzpnFCVRZ8M69vssbVitB95bG1JVCiLkdEjMjg0YlC9Ym68xo3/h2soLQeyn9PDFWUiH1YBf/tex9tqbwGy1ZeSEU4blBa/ktHM8Ga/a2tRuvTUT7dAVXpF17y/oVW4wT/D5SiK0josxGdaRrXMzWCfKjwZo43SpUXrhKPaZEpKF/y3rdv8Cw) Link includes test cases. Explanation: By transliterating the UTF-8 characters to uppercase letters we can avoid massive UTF-8 encoding penalties which would otherwise make the shortest solution a series of replacements one for each fraction character (154 bytes in total). Instead I can squeeze out a few bytes by sharing replacements between fractions with the same denominator and then again with the numerator, particularly with fifths and eighths.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>273</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>248</s></sup> 240 bytes

Saved 8 bytes thanks to [pppery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46076/pppery)!!!

```python
lambda s:{'¼':1/4,'½':.5,'¾':3/4,'⅐':1/7,'⅑':1/9,'⅒':.1,'⅓':1/3,'⅔':2/3,'⅕':.2,'⅖':.4,'⅗':.6,'⅘':.8,'⅙':1/6,'⅚':5/6,'⅛':1/8,'⅜':3/8,'⅝':5/8,'⅞':7/8}.get(s[0])or eval(s.replace('⁄','/').replace('⅟','1/'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZPNbptAFIX3fgrKZkAimJkBBpDcF0mycJ1xasl1EJAqqeVFpbpSd83/f/wiSRZ@FL@Ie@8dElMrldyR7pnvnsOMBzD5cfX5YCSX/c7Octj98mmva5XZmM2fWMbbocfmzyzzI5hfWCbRWEx/Y6SQTpBSpFO4iiOcoSWRzlkmDF1AKBAuAWiLK4AY4RogQbjBdWTdsiwydIcepff440QPmBI9sky1k4m/ryun3A523YPC0l@7Q6f0C50Puz3tsMX3H8xjbeY2rOkMLA6euyysjuUcsp1DocIe8yyDXDK3VemyKjG2YQGXtmfzNk0ihE1FqAADqBS6BOawnhc/f4FuzZ9B509oTGchrUYlGxxBDur8BURSCE/WpIpSRc2JsVKyUmpOjcUDc6iA2jNjmoNKas7xtDVfmDiiOKLmkmLDV3QIw9d4NzXfmGUxLYupuQWNar4zcUIx3f30nnYy/ECXGn4EVTXPzMkD223po1z3Kr2HTzrwAxWnQq5Uev/wUsXjKE15GohEhgH3Ao/7XESQRZ7d7w6GH@y3OfApWEmz1JvwUCSRauj/eGtjc6tRcm1sbMVr431LNCqsK64rqYu/s25TL/n7XOH7lnlJTZVqpbFYaaJede2Fuq0@fOqVp63ByPo2yB36Vr3Xv5KbtSwYVXFsAAd@yX2ncsnQRz2dV1nZYbQfIzMvBqPK6dvjamJtfbTG5cQaF9tlp6N3J7a7/AM)

A straight-up mapping of Unicode vulgar fractions to their values (`↉` (U+2189) falls into the *"don't care"* situation so throws an exception) or failing that, replaces `⅟` (U+215F) with `1/` (ASCII 49 + ASCII 47) and `⁄` (U+2044) with `/` (ASCII 47) and does an `eval`. So either returns the value (for valid input) or throws an exception (for invalid input).

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't remove `'↉':1` entirely, thereby causing that value to be treated as invalid and throw an exception?

Comment: @pppery Oh yeah, of course. Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>153</s> 151 bytes

```python
lambda s:F(s.translate({8260:47,8543:"1/"}))if s[1:]else F(numeric(s)).limit_denominator()
from fractions import Fraction as F
from unicodedata import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5LTsMwEAbgdXyKUVYxCqEtBapIZQU5BA9FJnGEpdiOxi5KhVggwZ73@3ERYNGj9CJhUMviG43s3zNupv7YmvWuGh90tdBHpQCXZpFLPArjauFldDoabPbS4VY82hiup2F/LTzjXFXg9vvpoaydhCwyEy1RFZHjPKmVVj4vpbFaGeEtRpxVaDVUKAqvrHGgdGPRQ7Y8AOEgW2QmRhW2lKXwYpla6ZZpN3Wssgj03IAWTeQ8JkQ18d8dtaUyPGWBxynVoIUxVPQjFsi2kI2HPYl2R50oRyt3EWkU7ZXtf1a2SZ4XtXAuz6kzQss8Z0GDyvgIZYM0K4ZwdTuMoeXd7IvNvtnsh80vr8g1uSG35I7ckwfySJ7IM3khr@SNvJMP8jlg/fn5xaL2fgE)

---

A not-so-lazy Python solution that returns the correct rational number as a `fraction.Fraction` instead of its floating point approximation.

### Explanation

We need to distinguish between two cases:

#### Case 1: input length ≠ 1

```python
Fraction( s.translate({ 8260: 47, 8543: "1/" }) )
```

Replace a couple of codepoints

- 8260<sub>10</sub> (U+2044, `⁄`) → 47<sub>10</sub> (U+002F, `/`)
- 8543<sub>10</sub> (U+215F, `⅟`) → `1/`

and parse the result as a `Fraction`.

#### Case 2: input length = 1

```python
Fraction(unicodedata.numeric(s)).limit_denominator(10)
```

Convert the input codepoint into its floating point representation using `unicodedata.numeric` and subsequently as a `Fraction`. Unfortunately the intermediate representation as a floating point value loses some precision and we need to approximate the intended value using `Fraction.limit_denominator` and the knowledge of the largest occurring denominator 1,000,000 (actually 10 but the [function’s default argument value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) is good enough).

Unfortunately we cannot merge the code paths for conversion to `Fraction` of both cases since the denominator limitation will return incorrect results for large denominators in case 1.

Answer (score 1):

Perl5:

```
perl -CiIO -Mutf8 -MUnicode::Normalize -pe '$_=NFKD$_'
```

Comment: Could you possibly add your byte count?

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-funsigned-char`, <strike>317</strike> <strike>239</strike> 234 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for the changes!

To save some size, I preload the numerator with `1` (the denominator will usually be set to `0` on test failures so that the function will return an invalid value: generally `NAN` or `INF`, but some of the "don't care" inputs give other values.) I then look for the common cases and return the result.

It's a somewhat brute-forced function, given that I'm not using any character classification or normalization to assist: I decode the first byte to determine whether I'm looking at a precomposed fraction or not, and then apply rules from what is found.

```c
#define S(x)strtol(x,&s,0)*!
n,d;float f(char*s){n=1;d=*s<58?n=S(s)0,*s|s[1]?s+=3,S(s)*s:0:*s-194?d=0[s+=2]-144,d<1?7:d<2?9:d<3?10:d<5?n=d-2,3:d<9?n=d-4,5:d<11?n=4*d-35,6:d<15?n=2*d-21,8:S(++s)*s:*++s<191?n=*s-187,4:0;return(n+.0)/d;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZBLbtswEIb3PIXqIAVJUykpybWe0SG8NLwwRNER4FCGhgYMuF4UaAt01/e7zUWSLHwUH6TqyOjim38ePzgYVv6qqvr@QtemsbU3ozsGrnPtmu7EUxCS8SfECp2Zdbt0nqHVzbLjwPa2UJkuOOSTuLTFjAKTgsMLmKtFCeMiFEOLQypTDr5KolIXco6DYOGrKBI6V@U01XlQJhjDUkmUCb6k/UCEmCfnPBITzJXCIuLaDyfi@VAPxgDrQIk4ndHx@LyKo@YqGczDzngqolRmXe22naV2fCXZM50d@ovmdtN2Lgenm/bq5prcLhtL2d603fk6D@axXAjuMrOqHVAQsRSD2bJss8XGaMTYvjHUFY3V9Q4NSjLGXSGzTddYZ@joErzi2rs0IwHC4Eew7HDoj/fk@ECOj@T0@h3yHvmAfEQ@IZ@RL8hX5BvyHfmB/ER@Ib@RP@R/406FJIhOL18F0ZQo1CmRJEGNSXSOpzdviY/rhpn8W5n1cgW9b7YWmpWttT9c@g8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

Prints a representation of a Ruby Rational type.

```ruby
$_=eval $_.unicode_normalize(:nfkc).sub ?⁄,"r/"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5BjlLsgqWlJWm6FjcNVeJtU8sScxRU4vVK8zKT81NS4_Pyi3ITczKrUjWs8tKykzX1ikuTFOwfNbboKBXpK0E0QvUv2PeodTbXo9b5hsZcRiZAJUYm5lyGQBpCGkBUAQA)