# Convert superscript numbers to normal numbers

Tags: code-golf, unicode, conversion

## Introduction

My gnome friends are writing a programming language and have asked for my help. Due to their size, the gnomes can only handle small superscript numbers instead of big numbers. However, the language they're writing the interpreter in only accepts big numbers!

## Your Challenge

Given an input of a superscript number (a series of characters that can be any of ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹), convert it to normal ASCII numbers and print the result. This is code golf, so shortest answer wins!

### Test Cases

```
¹ -> 1
⁵ -> 5
¹²³ -> 123
⁶⁵⁵³⁵ -> 65535
⁰¹²³ -> 123
```

Comment: Can you explain how the superscript part of the input is expected: is it UTF8 characters with codes 8304, 185, 178, 179, 8308, 8309, 8310, 8311, 8312 and 8313?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen The superscript numbers that are expected are exactly the characters `⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹`.

Comment: The reason that I ask is that I'm not absolutely confident that by copy-pasting from your question in my internet browser will give the correct characters.  Please could you specify in the question exactly what the characters should (or could) be?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Sure. The characters have unicode codepoints 2070, 00B9, 00B2, 2074, 2075, 2076, 2077, 2078, and 2079.

Comment: Um, that's only 9 codepoints... is it missing 00B3 = 179 for superscript '3'?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yes, sorry.

Comment: Can we return a list of digits?

Comment: @AaroneousMiller No, you must return the number.

Comment: Do we need to handle inputs starting with `⁰` (e.g. `⁰¹²³` -> `123`)? If so, please add one to the test cases.

Comment: @DLosc Good point. Yes, that should occur. I've updated the test cases.

Comment: I felt like I'd seen this same thing before, but it was smallcaps! Possibly related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60443/9365

Comment: There's got to be a short Perl6/Raku answer.

Comment: The new test case is invalidating most answers. :-/

Comment: `ord(⁰)` = 8304, `ord(¹)` = 185, `ord(²)` = 178... Unicode, you're drunk. -.-

Comment: related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205656/90841

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript, 20 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.normalize`NFKD`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NauWC8vvyg3MSezKjXBz83bJeF/QVFmXolGmob6oZ3qmppccO6jxq0o/EM7D206tBlNyTagKiA6tBmi@j8A)

Comment: +1 for finding the builtin.

Comment: `+s.normalize…` to remove leading zeros

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Edit: +1 to support `0123` -> `123` ...

```javascript
s=>+s.replace(/./g,c=>c.charCodeAt()%92%12)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k67WK8otSAnMTlVQ19PP10n2dYuWS85I7HIGajGsURDU9XSSNXQSPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmobSoZ1KmppcaIKPGrdiET2089CmQ5uxKt8G1AFEhzZj1/mocQNOzRCJR41bwEYADdr@qHHHo8adQD1A1f8B)

#### Conversion table

```
 char. | code | mod 92 | mod 12
-------+------+--------+--------
  '⁰'  | 8304 |   24   |   0
  '¹'  |  185 |    1   |   1
  '²'  |  178 |   86   |   2
  '³'  |  179 |   87   |   3
  '⁴'  | 8308 |   28   |   4
  '⁵'  | 8309 |   29   |   5
  '⁶'  | 8310 |   30   |   6
  '⁷'  | 8311 |   31   |   7
  '⁸'  | 8312 |   32   |   8
  '⁹'  | 8313 |   33   |   9
```

Comment: For the second one, you can get away with `c/58&c` .

Comment: @dingledooper Nice one! There's also `c%12&c` (found by Lynn). Unfortunately, the challenge update and OP comments suggest that this kind of answer is not valid anymore, so I'm removing it for now.

Answer (score 10):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), side length 4, 37 bytes

```
92},/%=\_@=..}{<.{\<.>".2//{%.1!}>'/_
```

### Unwrapped code:

```
    9 2 } ,
   / % = \ _
  @ = . . } {
 < . { \ < . >
  " . 2 / / {
   % . 1 ! }
    > ' / _
```

[Try it on hexagony.net](https://hexagony.net/#lzN4Igxg9gJgpiBcICcAmAvgGgPQFIC8AOgQPoACeAdBWsADwXBH0B8BIFKWWwOFAjAEI0zAORZiIDCACWAOwAOAVwAuCEIAcCAJ0AmgM2AXAkCuBIDcCQO4EgDwJAngSSZClQFlocRAEMATgHMQaIA===)

This is my first post on Code Golf, and first time using Hexagony. It's as painful as the name implies, but so satisfying to get a result! I ended up with more mirrors than I expected, but I'm pretty proud of what I achieved.

Credit to the previous users who worked out the modulo trick. My hexagon would have been a lot bigger without `%92%12`!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I haven't seen a Hexagony answer in ages, glad to see more usage of it!

Comment: It's rare to see a first post in Hexagony so well done! It doesn't look like `⁰` is handled correctly though: for inputs of `¹⁰` and `¹⁰¹` I'm seeing outputs of `1` and `11`, respectively.

Comment: Oh yeah! my test case started with ⁰, so I just didn't print it in order to stop leading zeroes from printing. I'll have to go back and fix it :)

Comment: I think the hexagony.net interpreter has changed to use byte by byte input now, but this should still work for codepoint inputs

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

*Edit +8 bytes to comply with the updated rules (`0123` -> `123`), but then -2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(s)el(chartr("⁰¹²³⁴-⁹","0-9",s):1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfkp@UmW77P600L7kkMz9Po1gzNUcjOSOxqKRIQ@lR44ZDOw9tOrT5UeMW3UeNO5V0lAx0LZV0ijWtDDUhWlEVPWrc@qhx26PG7Y8ad4DUa/4HAA)

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 57 bytes / <s>[25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/pfkp@UmW77P600L7kkMz9PI1kzWVXVzETXQksxWdfQwvR/Zl5JSH5oSZqFBlipRimQGZLvmVeiofSoccOhnYc2Hdr8qHHLo8atjxq3PWrc/qhxx6PGnUqampr/AQ) with IO as character codes</s>

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to pajonk, but then +6 bytes (again thanks to pajonk) to comply with the updated rules*

```r
function(s,x=utf8ToInt(s))el(intToUtf8(x%%64-8*!x-185):1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfkp@UmW77P600L7kkMz9Po1inwra0JM0iJN8zr0SjWFMzNUcjM68kJD8UKKhRoapqZqJroaVYoWtoYappZagJMUBD6VHjhkM7D206tPlR45ZHjVsfNW571Lj9UeOOR407lTT/AwA)

Function without multi-byte character codes, but sadly the verbose `utf8ToInt` and `intToUtf8` function names make it quite long if we want to accept input directly as a string...

The new rule that `⁰¹²³` should output `123` invalidates the second version with IO as character codes.  It could be fixed for [+17 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/pfkp@UmW77P600L7kkMz9PI1kzNUcjM68kJD@0JM1CI1lV1cxE10JLMVnX0MJU08pQE6JDoxQoG5LvmVeiofSoccOhnYc2Hdr8qHHLo8atjxq3PWrc/qhxx6PGnUqamv8B), but it's shorter to completely change approach (below), porting [Arnauld's charcode-to-digit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238482/95126) method.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes with IO as character codes

```r
function(c)c%%92%%12%*%10^rev(seq(!c)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfkp@UmW77P600L7kkMz9PI1kzWVXV0khV1dBIVUvV0CCuKLVMozi1UEMxWVPXUBOiXqO0JM0iJN8zr0RD6VHjhkM7D206tPlR45ZHjVsfNW571Lj9UeOOR407lTQ1/wMA)

Comment: You could save some bytes by I/O as char codes (as is by default allowed for string challenges) by removing `utf8ToInt` and `intToUtf8`.

Comment: @pajonk - That's an excellent suggestion.  Thankyou.  Now suddenly the nicer function seems more competitive...!

Comment: `(c==185)` -> `!c-185` for -2.

Comment: @pajonk - Neat!  Thanks again!

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/pfkp@UmW77P600L7kkMz9Po1gzNUcjOSOxqKRIQ@lR44ZDOw9tOrT5UeMW3UeNO5V0lAx0LZV0ijWtDDQhWlEVPWrc@qhx26PG7Y8ad4DUa/4HAA "R – Try It Online") for the `chartr` method with `el(<string>:0)`.

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks (yet) again.  That's particularly satisfying as it makes the original approach competitive again...!

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
O%12&ƊḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f1dBI7VjXwx09////f9S47VHjViA6tBlMbzi089AmEHsLmAuU3P6occejxp0A)

```
O         Get ordinal values
 %12&Ɗ    Apply x ↦ x%12&x
      Ḍ   Digits to number
```

I found the `x%12&x` formula by computer search. If I/O were super duper lenient, I guess `%12&` would be a valid 4-byte answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>46</s> 50 bytes

-1 thanks to ovs!

```python
lambda x:int(x.translate('%7d   45678923'%10*999))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjOvRKNCr6QoMa84J7EkVUNd1TxFQUHBxNTM3MLSyFhd1dBAy9LSUlPzf1p@kUKmQmaeQrT6oZ3qOgrqjxq3gqhDOw9tOrQZIrANKAZEhzZD5R41boBKx1opFBSBLEvTyNTUVFbQtVMwNDL@DwA)

Helper program to generate this: [helper](https://tio.run/##XY9NbsJADIX3nMK7GQOKQrtpkHISxCIUU1xgEnkG1C7nRqj/bHOUuUjqQWLD0tL3vffcvYdt6x6fOhmGTSvAwA6kcS9kqyk8lGWJ8xF4qMGY4rVlZ5@3YhnhDlbyik8YcQSS@RTP/aX/6D9T/ErxO8WfFH9T/EvxYoqgmt83gawfV1WlDm9gT856ClYQoa5hVmo1tMegaQsDZjlmva/FUzjlbnLHA0lOEZxncuELdmt6sydcquVD3qpSJ@w0lzqxtz@UxrwVVkLNbhj@AQ)

Comment: you need an `int()` around the whole thing

Comment: @Razetime other people are outputting as a string so I thought that was alright maybe

Comment: You can save a byte with `'%7d   45678923'%10*999`. But with according to the new test case you will have to add `int(...)`.

Comment: @ovs nice, clever

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 2 bytes

```
ＩＶ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npXv92z7//9R47ZHjVuB6NBmIAEA) Explanation:

```
 Ｖ  Eval as a Charcoal integer literal
Ｉ   Cast to string
    Implicitly print
```

Comment: verbose code in charcoal?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Correct me if I'm wrong _Neil_, but I don't think this program is possible in Verbose Charcoal, since it only has explicit inputs. So it would be `Cast(Evaluate(StringInput()))` or `Cast(Evaluate(q))`, which would actually be `ＩＶＳ` or `ＩＶθ` instead of `ＩＶ`. Unless there is a way for implicit inputs in Verbose Charcoal I'm unaware of, perhaps with a certain flag-argument?

Comment: Ha! Right language for the job. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Technically `Cast Evaluate` will parse in Verbose mode, but it doesn't really read like normal Verbose Charcoal, so I don't bother in such a case.

Answer (score 6):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), <sup><s>14</s> <s>10</s> <s>11</s></sup> 8 bytes

+1 and +4 to remove leading 0's.

-3 bytes thanks to [Moonchild](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51682/moonchild)!

```perl6
+~*.NFKD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPtfu05Lz8/N2@W/NReXnkqaXnFipUJafpFCTmZeavH/Qzu5HjVu5Tq089CmQ5uBzG1AHhAd2gwSfdS4ASLxqHELWBwou/1R445HjTsB)

---

## [Raku](https://raku.org) `-p`, <s>15</s> <s>19</s> bytes

-1 byte and -1 flag thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)!

```perl6
$_=+S:g{.}=$/.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18l3lY72Cq9Wq/WVkVfzzXM0ef//0M7uR41buU6tPPQpkObgcxtQB4QHdoMEn3UuAEi8ahxC1gcKLv9UeOOR407/@UXlGTm5xX/1y0AAA)

Raku uses superscript digits as exponents, but single digits on their own evaluate to their numeric value.

Comment: Can you not then take the 2-log of 2 with that exponent?

Comment: @Adám Yes that would work, but I think I still need `EVAL`, and the shortest I can do is `{log2 EVAL 2~$_}` at 16 bytes (Doesn't work on TIO because of old version)

Comment: @Adám that would be shorter with removing leading zeros, but as it is not working on TIO and returns `Inf` for the largest case, I'm not going to include it. [`{-1+chars EVAL 10~$_}`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/WtdQOzkjsahYwTXM0UfB0KBOJb72vzUXV1p@kUJOZl5qsYamQjWXgoKeSppecWIlV@3/Qzu5HjVu5Tq089CmQ5uBzG1AHhAd2gwSfdS4ASLxL7@gJDM/r/i/rq@vv5@3a6RusKurrp@/LsgeAA) would fix those issues, but is longer again.

Comment: I think you can shave off a couple of characters with `+~*.NFKD`

Comment: You can use `$/` instead of `$<>` and `EVAL` as a method to remove that extra flag. I really wish you could do `S:g{.}.=&EVAL` though

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>83</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>60</s></sup> 46 bytes

```c
n;f(int*s){for(n=0;*s;)n+=9*n+*s++%92%12;n=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBJTsMwFN33FF@RImVwRZO0QGTCBrHjBrSLyHVKBbhVHImIKgvfCDF326P4IITfOA1tJSx5@m@w32f9GWN1LWjmzEXhSXeVLXJHJAPqSeoKP4k94XvS9@04tIOQikTQqkYqPKZz4biw6gGOrRYKLosAErixNmutXix6CIUGet28afWu1ccxHjW4Vp9afWn1rdX6mDFszdHjXxd5O0HWqvkLMe@aLTLbsOoEwMslZwWfGkkwIBBGwxGB07PzmEAQbm8tnS2ELIDdpbmHK2f3PDcqa1xeh@MyvsI5sgjs3yOrVWNPYdtffHXKS5QNaHu8ADl/5ovM2f3FPWkLXleh4PsNe9ftv8BoZUI3@ITuwyARzZzCPaxyrHbBj2XLHCmZY9lT6F8CrrYcC0zV8AhI0oWXScInrXXVq@oflj2kM1n3n34B)

Inputs a pointer to a `wchar_t` string of superscript numbers.
Returns the normal number.

Discovered the `n % 92 % 12` formula independently.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
C:12%⋏ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJDOjEyJeKLj+G5hSIsIiIsIifigbbigbXigbXCs+KBtSciXQ==)

Port of Lynn's answer thanks to steffan.

Comment: I just commented for clarification that this was allowed before posting it lol, guess I got ninja'd. Sadge, since I already had the answer written up and everything.

Comment: That being said, you can use the `K` flag in 2.4.1 to get 6 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=92%2512%25&inputs=%E2%81%B0%C2%B9%C2%B2%C2%B3%E2%81%B4%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B9%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B4%C2%B3%C2%B2%C2%B9%E2%81%B0&header=&footer=)

Comment: According to OP, I guess a list of digits is invalid, so here's a valid 7 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=92%2512%25%E1%B9%85&inputs=%E2%81%B0%C2%B9%C2%B2%C2%B3%E2%81%B4%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B9%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B4%C2%B3%C2%B2%C2%B9%E2%81%B0&header=&footer=)

Comment: ^ This is invalid because list of digits is invalid. You can use lynn's formula though to keep the 7 bytes: `C:12%⋏ṅ`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
from unicodedata import*
lambda s:normalize("NFKC",s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehNC8zOT8lNSWxJFEhM7cgv6hEiysnMTcpJVGh2Covvyg3MSezKlVDyc/N21lJp1jz/38A)

Comment: if `unicodedata` module is not bulitin then change `Python 3` to `Python 3 + Unicodedata`

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I think it is builtin.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>65</s> <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/./g,x=>-~'¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'.search(x))
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602).*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974).*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563).*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NauWK8otSAnMTlVQ19PP12nwtZOt0790M5Dmw5tftS45VHj1keN2x41bn/UuONR4051veLUxKLkDI0KTc3/BUWZeSUaaRpA1eqamlxwLlAPCh9iGJqSbWCTt4IsAan@DwA)

Comment: `s=>s.replace(/./g,x=>'⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'.indexOf(x))` saves 3 bytes.

Comment: [Save another byte](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NauWK8otSAnMTlVQ19PP12nwtZOt0790M5Dmw5tftS45VHj1keN2x41bn/UuONR4051vcy8lNQK/zSNCk3N/wVFmXklGmkaQOXqmppccC5QEwofYhqakm1go7eCbAGp/g8A)

Comment: It should be safe to use `search` in place of `indexOf`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ç92%12%J
```

-3 bytes porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238482/52210) (thanks *@Neil* for the heads up).

Add a trailing `ï` (+1 byte) if you want to remove leading 0s..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//8OHOTIlMTIlSv//4oGwwrnCssKz4oG04oG14oG24oG34oG44oG5) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w@2WRqqGRqpe/3X@Rysd2qmko/SocSuQPLTz0KZDm8HcbUARIDq0GSLzqHEDRPJR4xawDFB@@6PGHY8adyrFAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç         # Convert the (implicit) input to a list of its codepoint-integers
          #  e.g. "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹" → [8304,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313]
 92%      # Modulo-92
          #  → [24,1,86,87,28,29,30,31,32,33]
    12%   # Modulo-12
          #  → [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
       J  # Join the list together
          #  → 0123456789
        ï # (Optionally) Remove leading 0s by casting to an integer
          #  → 123456789
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Apparently a list of digits isn't allowed?

Comment: @Neil Ah ok.. Added a join after it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Also, everyone seems to be porting @Arnauld's answer which I assume would be `Ç92%12%J` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>9</s> 12 bytes

*+3 bytes to handle more stringent rules*

```
+:A_%E#A_MJa
```

[Replit!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) (Note: the Unicode input seems not to play well with Pip's interactive mode, or maybe it's a Replit issue. For best results, Ctrl-C out of the default interactive mode and enter `./pip.py -e A_%E#A_Ma ⁶⁵⁵³⁵` at the command prompt.)

Or, here's a 14-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9waXD//ys6QV8lMioqI0FfTUph////4oGwwrnCssKz4oG04oG14oG24oG34oG44oG5)

#### Explanation

After some trial and error, I found a really nice property of these numbers' codepoints:

- ¹, ², and ³ have codepoints 185, 178, and 179. Mod 8 (or 4), these become 1, 2, and 3.
- The other superscript numbers have codepoints equal to the corresponding digit plus 8304. Mod 16 (or 12, or many other options), these become their respective digits.

So all we need to do is take the codepoint of each digit mod 8 if it's 3 digits and mod 16 if it's 4 digits...

```
          a  First command-line argument
        MJ   Map this function to each character, joining the results together:
  A_          Codepoint of the character
    %         Mod
     E        2 to the power of
      #       Length of
       A_     Codepoint of the character
+:           Treat the resulting string as a number (removing leading 0s)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), <s>46</s> 27 bytes

`I(j(ƒ(i %(%(↶(∋) 92) 12))))`

Uses Arnauld's 92/12 solution.

*Note: 3 bytes can be saved by removing the `I` instruction, however this version is not case 5-compliant.*

### Explanation

```
I(               Cast to integer
  j(             Join string (default is no seperator)
    ƒ(           List-builder for loop (returns a list of every returned value of the passed instruction)
      i          Get input
      %(         Modulo 2 (12)
        %(       Modulo 1 (92)
          ↶(     Get codepoint
            ∋    The current item in the for loop
          )
        92
        )
      12
      )
    )
  )
)
Implicit print
```

Old code (uses lookup table instead):

`v(0 []);f(i a(0 t(⌕("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹" ∋))));I(j(⁰))`

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

−1 byte thanks to rak1509

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires 0-based indexing.

```apl
10⊥'⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸'⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qG@qp/@jtgkGXGlAUuO/ocGjrqXqjxo3HNp5aNOhzY8atzxq3Pqocdujxu2PGnc8atyp/qh3839NLqA@oPo0pUM7leBsoEolJAmQfmTJbWCTtoIM3YosDrVK6T8A)

`10⊥` evaluate in base 10

`'⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸'⍳` the respective *i*ndices of the argument characters in this string (any character not in the string gets the first index beyond the end, i.e. 9)

Comment: Don't need the 9 in the string right?

Comment: @rak1507 Of course not. Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 19 bytes

```
T`⁰-⁹_¹²³`dd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JOFR4wbdR4074w/tPLTp0OaElJT//w/t5HrUuJULIgJkbgPygOjQZiABAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: `d` is a shorthand for `0123456789`. As `⁰-⁹` expands to `⁰ⁱ⁲⁳⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹`, and assuming none of `ⁱ⁲⁳` will appear in the input, those supserscript digits will get mapped to ASCII digits, while the `_¹²³` gets mapped to `0123` (the remaining digits in `d` get ignored). `_` is actually a placeholder on the LHS and does nothing except to skip `0` on the RHS (on the RHS it causes the character on the LHS to be deleted).

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Use Arnauld's formula so be sure to upvote him.

```
c %#\%C
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=YyAlI1wlQw&input=Ilx1MjA3MLmys1x1MjA3NFx1MjA3NVx1MjA3Nlx1MjA3N1x1MjA3OFx1MjA3OSI)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-funsigned-char`, 63 bytes

This version takes a string of UTF-8 characters. If the leading byte is `E2` then I mask the third byte with 15; otherwise I mask the second byte with 3. It's useful that `B9` (the trailing byte of ¹) is odd!

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;*s;s++)i=(*s++-226?*s&3:*++s&15)+i*10;i=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDNSsNAFIX38xSHSMvMJLFNamvrmAoVd8WdK3VRkqYdqIl0piKULvJGYv3LNo@SBzHOWEG4cH@@cy@HG/uLOG4aKVIaL2drrtg2zddURl3BlVCuy2REucl@GA4uuGr3zrjrqnbQZ67kQVfISIpdcySzeLVJ5jhXOpH58XJMSKeDqxDDAJNn0C5O0McApxhixCy7DDEZdSwLEKLHCJGZxsNMZvQplwnDlgDWE7i6vY9sBzhV6Xhw6uLdpqqsXqv9YfBhZiaq/R@ri5d/fKjq4u1XZKSfdfFVF6URGXx9M52a6zsPnGtBTGlfoCMlYHpo8wQ8ro27lDothWiMVnKXmUWuPaSUa8YE2TXfcbqaLVTjp5tMyUU2T3xr/wc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>6.5</s> 6 bytes (12 nibbles)

```
`@~.$`&%$12
```

A port of [Lynn's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238491/95126) comes out <s>half-a-byte</s> a byte shorter in [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html).

```
   .            # Map over 
    $           # the input string:
     `&         #  bitwise-and of
        $       #  each element
       %        #  modulo
         12     #  twelve
                #  and itself
`@~             # Finally, convert from base-10 digits
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

`lambda n: int("".join([str("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹".index(c))for c in n]))`

Thanks @Fmbalbuena!

Comment: `lambda n:int("".join([str("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹".index(c))for c in n]))` -2 bytes

Comment: `lambda n:int("".join(str("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹".index(c))for c in n))` will work, i think

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
dm(Sn%12c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9odXNr//9kbShTbiUxMmP///8i4oGwwrnCssKz4oG04oG14oG24oG34oG44oG5Ig)

Port of <s>[Arnauld's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238482/95126)</s> [Lynn's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238491/95126).

The 'charcode-to-charcode' [modulo-except-when-it's-185](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238472/95126) approach is discouragingly long in [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), but Lynn's 'charcode-to-digit' modulo-AND approach is very well-suited to [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk)'s `d` (digits to decimal number) function.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
<?=+iconv('','US//TRANSLIT',$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WOzM5P69MQ11dRz00WF8/JMjRL9jHM0RdRyWxKD1P0/r//0eNGw7tPLTp0OZ/@QUlmfl5xf913QA)

Some nice PHP builtin

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```
import strutils,unidecode
stdin.readAll.unidecode.parseInt.echo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEobikqLQkM6dYpzQvMyU1OT8llau4JCUzT68oNTHFMSdHDy6uV5BYVJzqmVeil5qckf///6PGDYd2Htp0aPOjxm2PGrcCEYi5FQA)

If removing leading zeros is not required:

### [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```
import unidecode
stdin.readAll.unidecode.echo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEoTQvMyU1OT8llau4JCUzT68oNTHFMSdHDy6ul5qckf///6PGDYd2Htp0aPOjxm2PGrcCEYi5FQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/#SyntaxInfo), 99 bytes

```
* ⁰ 0 r *
* ¹ 1 r *
* ² 2 r *
* ³ 3 r *
* ⁴ 4 r *
* ⁵ 5 r *
* ⁶ 6 r *
* ⁷ 7 r *
* ⁸ 8 r *
* ⁹ 9 r *
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/?86ef941bf68261e77f4e6e876cfe6ae7)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.tr("⁰-⁹¹²³","0-9123").to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivpEhD6VHjBt1HjTsP7Ty06dBmJR0lA11LQyNjJU29kvz4zNr/BQpp0SA1EPlHjVseNW591LjtUeP2R407gPqUYrnASg7tBCnaBCKAqjaAFW4Aq90AVr4BrGMDWBOQBKlWiv0PAA)

Comment: Doesn't work for the last testcase.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>72</s> 63 bytes

<sup>Saved 9 bytes thanks to [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238462/convert-superscript-numbers-to-normal-numbers/238512?noredirect=1#comment560546_238512)</sup>

```
=--CONCAT(MOD(MOD(UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),92),12))
```

Not very exciting, really. It's the Excel version of [Arnauld's answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238482/38183)

- `MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)` pulls each character from the input one at a time.
- `MOD(MOD(UNICODE(MID(~)),92),12))` converts that character to unicode and then takes the mod 92 and mod 12.
- `--CONCAT(MOD(~))` combines all those code values into a string and then coerces that string into a number by making it negative twice (so back to positive again) which also will drop any leading zeros.

Comment: Using `CONCAT()` and the double unary can save a few bytes here: `=--CONCAT(MOD(MOD(UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),92),12))` == 63 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 13 bytes

```
[ nfkd dec> ]
```

`nfkd` postdates the build TIO uses, so have a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: [ATO link](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc2s0GBPP3crhezUorzUHIXSvMzk_JRUhdzEkgy9gsSi4tQihYKi1JKSyoKizLwShcJyheLUwtLUvOTUYgVrLq7C8mqFQzsVHjVuBVKHNh3aDGRuA_KA6NBmkOijxg1QidqlpSVpuhZroxXy0rJTFFJSk-0UYiFiS3MTCxT0IOwFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 94 bytes

```lua
r=0 t={[185]=1,[178]=2,[179]=3}for _,c in utf8.codes(...)do r=r*10+(t[c]or c-8304)end print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/yNZAocS2OtrQwjTW1lAn2tDcItbWCERbxtoa16blFynE6yQrZOYplJakWegl56ekFmvo6elppuQrFNkWaRkaaGuURCfHAtUl61oYG5hopualKBQUZeaVaBRp/v///1HjhkM7QcSmQ5sB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 40 bytes

```
A+O:-unicode_nfkd(A,C),atom_number(C,O).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/31Hb30q3NC8zOT8lNT4vLTtFw1HHWVMnsSQ/Nz6vNDcptUjDWcdfU@@/la5CbmJBTmZxiUZ0RKydnUaEtr9OeVFmSWpOnoa/pqZOtNKhnUo6So8atwLJQzsPbTq0GczdBhQBokObITKPGjdAJWOBpgIA)

Builtins

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$9\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.408 bytes

```
_O%12%92C
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJfTyUxMiU5MkMiLCLigbbigbXigbXCs+KBtSJd)

```
_O%12%92C 
        C # Convert to charcodes
     %92  # Mod 92
  %12     # Mod 12
 O        # Join the list of digits
_         # Cast to number to get rid of leading 0s
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>78</s> 71 bytes

```julia
~x=parse(Int,join(Dict(["⁰¹²³"...;'⁴':'⁹'].=>0:9)[i] for i=x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9NasMwEIXX0SmGbCyBa/KDC01R6KKbniGEoCRqmWBkI43Bq4BvFJo24K2O4ou4cm0SGIbHe9/AvFOZoZpXXXeuZKGs0/zDUHzK0fB3PBDfTNv64hv/7a/TJEleo7b@iVZhN9E2kevZ6kVscAufuQWUlRBdr0g72h2U04AGrFbHDI12XLCJimEXwx4kuCJD4ndSMDZBU5TUR2TRfHEV@LykwXv8BvuefVPOaUtwHo8kDCjT5tj5Bp7WMGdt/duLlA0F/s3FMti3kITx15F4TtNlyu5NR/AP)

- -3 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use range directly, no need to vectorize with `[0:9;]`
- -4 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use array comprehension instead of an anonymous function, removing one occurrence of the splat operator `...`

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY9NasMwEIXX0SmGrCRwTdPgQgsKXXTTM4QQlEQtE4xspDF4FdCNQn7aeuuj6CKuZYd093jzDbxvX@WoZnXXHWpZKus0/zCU7As0/B23xJfT4I9t057ac/CX4K/Bfwf/E/xv8M00TdNVKhePry9iiSv4LCygrIXoYiLtaL1VTgMasFrtcjTaccEmKoF1AhuQ4Mocid9JwdgETVlRPJFF88VVzxcVjd3/QthE9k05py3B4fYkYUSZNruubeBhATPWj44hY6PGUD7N2SDS61yj2UA8Z9k8Y3ffG/gH)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 67 bytes

```java
s->java.text.Normalizer.normalize(s,java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFKD)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDPisJADMbP9ikGT62seQFdT4sXWT2IJ/EQaytTpzPDTCpW8eArKS54nUfZF@lm/3hb0BDIl@TjF0iBW@wWq00jS2sciYJ7qEgqyCudkjQaOr3IVkslU5Eq9F68o9TiEAmOv7knJC5bI1ei5G08JSf1er4Q6NY@YXNrptHVE5s5JOP6v/uByF8b3x383KRsRzA2rkQl95kDfZexf/nXMGQJ4@HoLWl6UWtae8pKMBWBZTYpHeeA1qo6bodbO0keeD5P18emcAvncHkG9sE8znC5c7@/dYyOzRc)

Comment: Java wins longest builtin again?

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 75 bytes

```hs
f=mapM(\x->[putStr$show k|k<-[0..],x=="⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"!!k]!!0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802N7HAVyOmQtcuuqC0JLikSKU4I79cIbsm20Y32kBPL1anwtZW6VHjhkM7D206tPlR45ZHjVsfNW571Lj9UeOOR407lRQVs2MVFQ00/@cmZuYp2CqkKeBV/h8A)

Comment: [68 if you cut out the IO](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hxzYlX6HYRjfHOro4I79cIbsm20Y32kBPL1an2NZW6VHjhkM7D206tPlR45ZHjVsfNW571Lj9UeOOR407lRQVs2MVFQ3@5yZm5inYKhQUZeaVKKgopCng1fUfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
ą2Ĩ4+1ᴇ%ǰƖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9weXT//8SFMsSoNCsx4bSHJcewxpb//@KBsMK5wrLCs@KBtOKBteKBtuKBt@KBuOKBuQ)

```
ą                 implicit input; convert to ąrray of characters
 2Ĩ               due to oversight in implementing arbitrary-base integer
                  Ĩnterpretation, this returns the position for each character
                  in the list of potential base characters (which is a contiguous
                  stretch)
   4+             add 4 to each
     1ᴇ%          modulo 10
        ǰ         ǰoin without delimiters
         Ɩ        cast to Ɩnteger; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
OD12%z.A&ZD
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhar_V0MjVSr9BzVolwgIlCJBSsfNW44tPPQpkObIQIA)

Port of Lynn's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
OD12%z.A&ZD  # Implicit input
OD           # Get ordinals and duplicate
  12%        # Mod 12 of each
     z.      # Zip and apply to each pair:
       A&    #  Bitwise AND
         ZD  # Convert to integer
             # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```python
lambda s:int(''.join(str(x%12&x)for x in map(ord,s)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXMSc5NSEhWKrTLzSjTU1fWy8jPzNIpLijQqVA2N1Co00_KLFCoUMvMUchMLNPKLUnSKNTU1IZo3FhSBNKVpZOYVlJZowMUXrHzUuOHQzkObDm2GCAAA)

Port of Lynn's Jelly answer. Not the best Python answer (by 3 bytes), but uses a different method to the others.

Answer (score -2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 89 bytes

```python
lambda a:int(a.translate(dict(zip(map(ord,"⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"),"0123456789"))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKjOvRCNRr6QoMa84J7EkVSMlM7lEoyqzQCM3sUAjvyhFR@lR44ZDOw9tOrT5UeOWR41bHzVue9S4/VHjjkeNO5U0dZQMDI2MTUzNzC0slTSB4H9BEcjINA0lsMItpKBtQBP@AwA)

-77 Bytes thanks to @grandBagel

-31 Bytes thanks to @ovs

Comment: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHRKlGvpCgxrzgnsSRVo1rpUeMGJSslAyUdpUM7gYQhiLEJKGIEYmwGMoyBjEeNW4AsEzBrK5BlCmZtA7LMwKztQJY5mLUDyLIAs3YCWZZKtZr//wMA should work

Comment: @grandBagel nope syntaxerror

Comment: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHRKlGvpCgxrzgnsSRVo1rpUeMGJSslAyUdpUM7gQxDEGMTkGEEYmwGMoyBjEeNW4AsEzBrK5BlCmZtA7LMwKztQJY5mLUDyLIAs0CmWSrVav7/DwA surely works

Comment: This currently returns the input unchanged as the dictionary keys have to be codepoints instead of strings. [Here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKjOvRCNRr6QoMa84J7EkVSMlM7lEoyqzQCM3sUAjvyhFR@lR44ZDOw9tOrT5UeOWR41bHzVue9S4/VHjjkeNO5U0dZQMDI2MTUzNzC0slTSB4H9BEcjINA0lsMItpKBtQBP@AwA) is a 89 byte version that actually works